# Plotting piecewise function with distinct colors in each section

Tags: plotting, functions, piecewise

I have a piecewise function that I would like to plot but I was wondering if it is possible that each part of the function that is plotted when its corresponding condition is true be plotted with a different color from the other parts. That is, if I have a Piecewise function `Piecewise[{{val1, cond1},{val2,cond2},{val3,cond3}}]` then I want `val1`, `val2`, and `val3` to be plotted with different colors so that I can differentiate each case in the plot.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach than Spartacus' answer. What he did is splitting up the piecewise function into many different functions valid in only a small domain; what I am doing here is directly plotting the piecewise function as given, while the coloring is done using `ColorFunction`.

I'll use the same function as Spartacus,

```
f = Piecewise[{{#^2, # <= 0}, {#, 0 < # <= 2}, {Log[#], 2 < #}}] &
```

## Step by step to the result

Now let's create a `ColorFunction` that does the desired thing out of this. I'll do this using [`Part`, i.e. double brackets `[[ ]]`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUHX0.png), which is not limited to lists only.

First, create a copy of `f`.

```
colorFunction = f;
```

Now we need to find out how many pieces there are in this function; for this we have to extract those into a list we can allpy `Length` to. Step by step:

```
colorFunction[[1]]
```

> ```
> Piecewise[{{#1^2, #1 <= 0}, {#1, Inequality[0, Less, #1, LessEqual, 2]}, {Log[#1], 2 < #1}}, 0]
> ```

That's the full function body. By applying another `[[1]]`, we can get the first argument of `Piecewise`:

```
colorFunction[[1, 1]]
```

> ```
> {{#1^2, #1 <= 0}, {#1, 0 < #1 <= 2}, {Log[#1], 2 < #1}}
> ```

From this matrix-shaped list, we'd like to get the length, leaving us with

```
piecewiseParts = Length@colorFunction[[1,1]]
```

Alright! Now make some colors out of that. The default plot colors are stored in `ColorData[1][x]`, where `x=1,2,3,4...` is the usual blue/magenta/yellowish/green and so on.

```
colors = ColorData[1][#] & /@ Range@piecewiseParts
```

> ```
> {RGBColor[0.2472, 0.24, 0.6], RGBColor[0.6, 0.24, 0.442893], RGBColor[0.6, 0.547014, 0.24]}
> ```

Now we need to take these color directives and inject them into the original function (that is, the `colorFunction` copy I've made in the beginning), so that it replaces squares and logarithms by reds and blues. This is some more `Part` acrobatics:

```
colorFunction[[1, 1, All, 1]] = colors
```

Done! `colorFunction` is now identical to the original function `f`, only that the actual functions have been replaced by colors. It looks like this:

```
Piecewise[{{RGBColor[...], # <= 0}, {RGBColor[...], 0 < # <= 2}, {RGBColor[...], 2 < #}}] &
```

Now it's time to plot, see the completed code below.

## The completed code

```
f = Piecewise[{{#^2, # <= 0}, {#, 0 < # <= 2}, {Log[#], 2 < #}}] &;

colorFunction = f;
piecewiseParts = Length@colorFunction[[1, 1]];
colors = ColorData[1][#] & /@ Range@piecewiseParts;
colorFunction[[1, 1, All, 1]] = colors;

Plot[
    f[x],
    {x, -2, 4},
    ColorFunction -> colorFunction, 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False
]
```

[image: final plot]

(The option `ColorFunctionScaling` determines whether Mathematica scales the domain for the color function to $[0,1]$. Handy in some cases, not so much here, since our self-made `colorFunction` is constant in this domain.)

Comment: Ack, you've done what I was going to do! +1, of course!

Comment: smooth L1.  $0.5x^2$, if $\mid x\mid<1$; otherwise $\mid x\mid -0.5$. `f = Piecewise[{{0.5 #^2, Abs[#] < 1}, {Abs[#] - 0.5,  Abs[#] >= 1}, {Log[#], 2 < #}}] &;` works fine with two colors.

Answer (score 19):

Here is one method, now more robust:

```
pwSplit[_[pairs : {{_, _} ..}]] := Piecewise[{#}, Indeterminate] & /@ pairs

pwSplit[_[pairs : {{_, _} ..}, expr_]] := 
  Append[pwSplit@{pairs}, pwSplit@{{{expr, Nor @@ pairs[[All, 2]]}}}]
```

Testing:

```
pw = Piecewise[{{x^2, x < 0}, {x, 2 > x > 0}, {Log[x], x > 2}}];

Plot[Evaluate[pwSplit@pw], {x, -2, 4}, PlotStyle -> Thick, Axes -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
pw = Integrate[Piecewise[{{E^x, x^2 <= 1}}, Sin[x]], x];

Plot[Evaluate[pwSplit @ pw], {x, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

I like Heike's method so much I have to do my own version of it.

```
Module[{i = 1},
  Plot[pw, {x, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
    /. x_Line :> {ColorData[1][i++], x}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This plots the functions as zero out of their piecewise domain. You can get rid of this behavior by using `Piecewise[{#, {Indeterminate, True}}]` instead. However, this assumes that the original `Piecewise` does not use a `True` directive already.

Comment: @David, thanks, that works well.

Comment: @filo you're welcome and thanks for the Accept.

Comment: smooth L1.  $0.5x^2$, if $\mid x\mid<1$; otherwise $\mid x\mid -0.5$. `f = Piecewise[{{0.5 #^2, Abs[#] < 1}, {Abs[#] - 0.5,  Abs[#] >= 1}, {Log[#], 2 < #}}] &;` works fine with two colors.

Answer (score 17):

It looks like `Plot` is kind enough to split a plot of a `Piecewise` function in separate `Line` objects, so you could do something like

```
pl = Plot[Piecewise[{{x^2, x < 0}, {x, 2 > x > 0}, {Log[x], 3 > x > 0}}], 
  {x, -2, 4}];
lines = Cases[pl, _Line, Infinity];
Graphics[Transpose[{Array[ColorData[1], Length[lines]], lines}], Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Beautiful. I almost checked this possibility but then I thought "Piecewise is supposed to be continuous; it won't work."  I am glad somebody bothered to check.

Comment: smooth L1.  $0.5x^2$, if $\mid x\mid<1$; otherwise $\mid x\mid -0.5$ will be treated as three pieces and be plotted with three colors.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to split up the `Piecewise` function into pieces and use [`ConditionalExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html).

```
getPieces[f_Piecewise] :=
 Append[ConditionalExpression @@@ First@ f,
  ConditionalExpression[Last@ f, ! Or @@ f[[1, All, 2]]]]
```

Borrowing an example from [Plotting piecewise functions with distinct colors - issue found](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96337/plotting-piecewise-functions-with-distinct-colors-issue-found), we can plot it as follows. (Note `ColorData[100]` is from V10.  Another color scheme may be used of course.)

```
pw = Piecewise[{
  {7.95*^6 + x (0.0307 - 2.1558*^-11 x - 1.1279*^-18 x^2) - 507300. Log[6.371*10^6 + 1. x],
    0 <= x <= 7157200},
  {8.01*^6 + x (0.0220 - 2.1558*^-11 x - 1.1279*^-18 x^2) - 507300. Log[6.371*10^6 + 1. x],
    7157200 <= x <= 14314400},
  {8.05*^6 + x (0.0190 - 2.1558*^-11 x - 1.1279*^-18 x^2) - 507300. Log[6.371*10^6 + 1. x],
    14314400 <= x <= 21471600},
  {8.07*^6 + x (0.0180 - 2.1558*^-11 x - 1.1279*^-18 x^2) - 507300. Log[6.371*10^6 + 1. x],
    21471600 <= x <= 28628800},
  {8.08*^6 + x (0.0179 - 2.1558*^-11 x - 1.1279*^-18 x^2) - 507300. Log[6.371*10^6 + 1. x],
    28628800 <= x <= 35786000}},
 0];

Plot[Evaluate[getPieces[pw]], {x, 0, 35786000}, PlotStyle -> ColorData[100]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that for this particular code, one might use `ConditionalExpression` more directly with

```
Plot[Evaluate[ConditionalExpression @@@ First@pw], {x, 0, 35786000}, 
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[100]]
```

since the default is not used over this interval.

One can also apply [`PiecewiseExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PiecewiseExpand.html) to `pw` in cases where the inequalities might need simplifying; `PiecewiseExpand` might also reorder the pieces.  (It does on `pw`.)

Comment: It might be safer to extract data with ``Internal`FromPiecewise``. Something like ``getPieces[f_Piecewise] := MapThread[ConditionalExpression[#2, #1] &, Internal`FromPiecewise[f]]``

Comment: @ChipHurst Thanks.  It seems like it correlates the default value to `True`, so I'd still need to replace it with complement of the other domains. But it is a nice way to get all the conditions & expressions.

Comment: Ah! You're right!

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

```
pw = Piecewise[{{x^2, x < 0}, {x, 2 > x > 0}, {Log[x], x > 2}}];
pw = pw // PiecewiseExpand // Simplify;(* normalization *)
conds = First[pw][[All, 2]]; k = Length[conds]; (* get conditions *)
Plot[pw, {x, -2, 4}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[x, 
   Evaluate[
    Piecewise[Transpose[{ColorData[1] /@ Range[k], conds}], 
     ColorData[1][k + 1]]]], ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[3], Axes -> None, Frame -> True]
```

[image: plot of piecewise function, with different colors]

Changing the coloring scheme should be straightforward.