# How do I plot a function over a subset of the displayed interval?

Tags: plotting

I want to plot `f1[x]` over `0 < x < L/2` and `f2[x]` over `L/2 < x < L` (i.e. so that `f1[x]` isn't displayed over`L/2 < x < L`, etc.). How do I do this?

Comment: You could use Piecewise for instance.

Comment: Related:  [Plotting piecewise function with distinct colors in each section](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1128/121)

Comment: Strongly related: "[Can I limit PlotRange for 1 function in a Plot?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7102/280)" The presented solution with `ConditionalExpression` is even more succinct than with `Piecewise`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As b.gatessucks commented, use [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Piecewise.html).  For example:

```
f1[x_] := Sin[x]
f2[x_] := Cos[x]

L = 7;

pw = Piecewise[{{f1@#, 0 < # < L/2}, {f2@#, L/2 < # < L}}, Indeterminate] &;

Plot[pw[x], {x, 0, L}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Generally you should not use capital letters for variable names (`L`) but I kept your notation in this case.

Answer (score 8):

We needn't use `Piecewise`, alternatively one can use `Condition` (`/;`) and/or `ConditionalExpression` (new in `version 8`).

```
f1[x_] := Sin[x]
f2[x_] := Cos[x]
```

Here are respective definitions :

```
f[x_] /; 0 <= x <= Pi := f1[x]
f[x_] /; Pi < x <= 2 Pi := f2[x]
```

or a sligtly different way :

```
ff[x_] /; x <= L/2 := f1[x]
ff[x_] /; L/2 < x  := f2[x]
```

we can do a similar construction in a more flexible way assuming e.g. dependence of the function on the parameter `L` :

```
g[x_, L_] /; 0 <= x <= L    := ConditionalExpression[f1[x], 0 <= x <= L]
g[x_, L_] /; L <  x <= 2 Pi := ConditionalExpression[f2[x], L < x <= 2 Pi]
```

to plot these functions we can make use of e.g. `Exclusions` option, let's demonstrate how it works :

```
GraphicsRow[{ Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Exclusions -> {x == Pi}],
              Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}] }]
```

[image]

In case of `ff` function we can use `RegionFunction` option, to plot an appropriately restricted range, e.g.

```
L = 2 Pi;
GraphicsRow[{ Plot[ ff[x], {x, 0, L}, Exclusions -> {x == Pi}, PlotStyle -> Thick], 
              Plot[ ff[x], {x, -Pi/2, 5/2 Pi}, Exclusions -> {x == Pi}, 
                    PlotStyle -> Thick, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, L > x > 0]] }]
```

[image]

We show here something more customized :

```
Animate[ Plot[ g[x, L], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2 Pi}, {-1.05, 1.05}},
              Exclusions -> {x == L}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01],
              ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors", ImageSize -> {500, 500}], 
         {L, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Or without the use of piecewise:

```
gg1 = Plot[Cos[x], {x, \[Pi]/2 + $MachineEpsilon, \[Pi]}];
gg2 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, \[Pi]/2}];

Show[gg2, gg1, PlotRange -> {{0, \[Pi]}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is a more integrated  version with it bundled up into  a function which takes a list of functions to plot and an arbitrary number of ranges:

```
Clear[DisjointRangePlot2D];
DisjointRangePlot2D[fs_List, xRanges_List] := 
 Module[{x}, 
  Show[MapThread[
    Plot[#1[x], Evaluate@Flatten@{x, #2}] &, {fs, xRanges}], 
   PlotRange -> {{Min@First@(xRanges\[Transpose]), 
      Max@Last@(xRanges\[Transpose])}, Automatic}]]
DisjointRangePlot2D[f_, xRanges_List] := 
 DisjointRangePlot2D[Table[f, {Length@xRanges}], xRanges]
```

A selected plot with a single function:

```
DisjointRangePlot2D[Sin, {{0, \[Pi]}, {2 \[Pi], 4 \[Pi]}, {7 \[Pi], 10 \[Pi]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A plot with multiple functions and ranges:

`DisjointRangePlot2D[{Sin, Cos,  Cos}, {{0, \[Pi]}, {2 \[Pi], 4 \[Pi]}, {7\[Pi], 10 \[Pi]}}]`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I did play with passing `opts:OtpionsPattern[]` to `Plot` or `Show` to give more control over the final output,  but I didn't succeed in making that work.

Comment: This works in this case, but one should be aware that the option settings of the first plot are used, so this may lead to unintended results sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

`Piecewise` would work but displays a spurious line at `0` vertical coordinate:

```
f[x_] := Sin[x];
Plot[Piecewise[{{f[x], x < 2 Pi}}], {x, 0, 4 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(note the horizontal line for $x>2\pi$).

One can avoid this by simply displaying a bigger range than has been plotted, as follows:

```
Show[
 Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}],
 PlotRange -> {{0, 4 Pi}, {-1, 1}}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There is now nothing at $x>2\pi$.

Comment: Or just use `Indeterminate`. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yes I saw it in your answer. didn't think of it!

Comment: It is not spurious either, because the default value if none of the conditions apply, is 0.

Comment: @R.M Right, I meant "undesirable". Sorry for the confusion