# Can I limit PlotRange for 1 function in a Plot?

Tags: plotting

I have a 2D Plot of 3 functions

```
Plot[ { f1[x], f2[x], f3[x] }, { x, 8, 18 } ]
```

where I want f3[x] only plotted for the range [10, 18] instead of [8, 18]. Is that possible?

Comment: Related:http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5858/how-do-i-plot-a-function-over-a-subset-of-the-displayed-interval/5862#5862

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `ConditionalExpression` (new in version 8) e.g.

```
Plot[{f1[x], f2[x], ConditionalExpression[f3[x], x > 10]}, {x, 8, 18}]
```

For example, let's define :

```
f1[x_] := -4/5 Sin[x]
f2[x_] := Sin[2 x]^2 - 1/2
f3[x_] := Sin[3 x]^5
```

now

```
Plot[{ f1[x], f2[x], ConditionalExpression[f3[x], x > 10]}, {x, 8, 18},
       PlotStyle -> {Thick, Thick, Thickness[0.007]}]
```

[image]

The thickest curve is the graph of of `f3` in the expected region though `f3` is defined for all real (even complex) numbers.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Alternatively, there's `Plot[{f1[x], f2[x], Piecewise[{{f3[x], x > 10}}, Indeterminate]}, {x, 8, 18}]`.

Comment: @stevenvh I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @J.M. that version also works on v7 whereas `ConditionalExpression` does not.  Please post that as an answer, or I shall.

Answer (score 9):

A solution using individual plots combined using `Show`.

```
f1[x_] := 1/4 Sin[x]
f2[x_] := 1/2 Sin[2 x]^2
f3[x_] := Sin[3 x]^3
```

Define a function to plot some functions over some ranges:

```
Attributes@plotFuncs = {HoldFirst};
plotFuncs[{funcs_, ranges_, opts_}] := 
 Show[Block[Evaluate@Union@ranges[[All, 1]], 
   MapThread[
    Plot[#1[First@#2], #2, #3] &, {funcs, ranges, 
     opts}]], PlotRange -> All]
```

Plot the three functions:

```
plotFuncs[{{f1, f2, f3}, {{x, 8, 18}, {y, 8, 18}, {x, 10, 18}}, 
{PlotStyle -> Red, PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotStyle -> Darker@Green}}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm a beginner at Mathematica, and accepted Artes' answer because it's easier to understand. But thanks again.

Comment: #@stevenvh No problem, glad you got the answer you needed :)

Answer (score 7):

At Mr. Wizard's urging: `Plot[{f1[x], f2[x], Piecewise[{{f3[x], x > 10}}, Indeterminate]}, {x, 8, 18}]` works nicely as an alternative to Artes's answer.