# How to make the Show function work in this case?

Tags: functions

I can't get this to work, the Show function shows only the first plot. Why this happens and how to solve it?

```
Show[Plot[x^2, {x, 2, 10}], Plot[1 - x, {x, 1, -10}]]
```

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7102/can-i-limit-plotrange-for-1-function-in-a-plot

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason this happens is that the `Show` command uses the `PlotRange` options of the first plot, which in this case is disjoint with the range of the second plot, So you have to tell it to show all relevant regions by doing

```
Show[Plot[x^2, {x, 2, 10}], Plot[1 - x, {x, 1, -10}], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: show]

Comment: Congrats on 10k! :)

Comment: @R.M Thanks - saving the world, 10 rep points at a time...