# Show function seems to be broken

Tags: plotting, functions

I read the thread [How to make the Show function work in this case?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7496/how-to-make-the-show-function-work-in-this-case). I think I have the same problem as discussed there. But when I try the to evaluate

```
Show[Plot[x^2, {x, 2, 10}], Plot[1 - x, {x, 1, -10}], 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

it doesn't work. The output:

[image: looks like it did nothing?].

How can I fix it?

---

Update:
This comes after`Clear["*", All];`. 
`Clear["*", All];
Show[Plot[x^2, {x, 2, 10}], Plot[1 - x, {x, 1, -10}], 
 PlotRange -> All]` makes it failed.

Comment: Have you played with `$DisplayFunction`? What if you evaluate `$DisplayFunction = Identity`?

Comment: @Kuba Now I can't reproduce it after restart Mathematica for several times... Why should I evaluate `$DisplayFunction = Identity`? What's `Identity`? I have never heard it before.

Comment: Both of those symbols can be looked up by pressing F1.

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem. I get the expected plot when I evaluate your code with V10.4.1 running on OS X 10.10.2.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  the problem the user is experiencing can not be reproduced by others.

Comment: @m_goldberg I know what I did. Add `Clear["*", All];` before the command can reproduce it. I can't see why Claer makes it failed.

Comment: [(5682)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5682/121) may interest you, as well as the documentation for [`$DisplayFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$DisplayFunction.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Clear["*"]` clears every symbol found on `$ContextPath` which is not `Protected`. So many `` System` `` symbols too...

Moreover, unless you want to double clear `` System`All ``, `Clear["*", All]` is made up syntax.

What you probably want is `` Clear["Global`*"] `` or `` ClearAll["Global`*"] ``

Weren't you warned by:

[image]

Comment: Ergo, `Show` appeared to be broken because the OP broke it.