# How to restrict the domain of a function

Tags: function-construction, conditional, argument-patterns

I realize this question has been asked many times, but I am fairly new at Mathematica and the other answers are very complex, and certainly too complicated for this simple code I am trying to write.

I want to restrict the function below to be between -1 and 1. *I do not want to restrict the plot*; I want to restrict the function itself.

```
f[x_] := -(x + c)^2
```

Is there a simple way I can do this?

Comment: Is this what you are after: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html?

Comment: So far I haven't had any luck with this method. I suppose I could be doing it wrong though.

Comment: I prefer `ConditionalExpression`  than `Condition`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I limit PlotRange for 1 function in a Plot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7102/can-i-limit-plotrange-for-1-function-in-a-plot)

Comment: Try this: `f[x_]:=If[-1<=x<=1, -(x+c)^2, Nothing]`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) which has the operator form `/;`.

```
f[x_ /; -1 <= x <= 1, c_] := -(x + c)^2
```

Then

```
With[{c = -1/4}, Plot[f[x, c], {x, -2, 2}]]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: This worked! Thank you!

Comment: @Physika consider also reading [(1835)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1835/121)

Answer (score 4):

Amplifying on m_goldberg's answer: The [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) can include a [`Message`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Message.html) to use when the argument is outside the allowed interval.

```
ClearAll[f]

f::arg = "Argument value of `1` must be in the closed interval {-1, 1}.";

f[x_, c_] /; If[TrueQ[-1 <= x <= 1], True, Message[f::arg, x]] := -(x + c)^2
```

Then, an argument outside the interval generates a `Message`

```
f[2, c]
```

[image]

The `Message` can be turned [`Off`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Off.html)

```
With[{c = -1/4}, Off[f::arg]; Plot[f[x, c], {x, -2, 2}]]
```

[image]