# Restrict the domain of a function (and plot) it) when it depends on the value of a parameter

Tags: plotting, function-construction, conditional, argument-patterns, parameters

I know similar questions have been asked, but I am very new at Mathematica and other questions/answers are quite complex and do not suit the code I want to write.

I want to restrict the domain of the function f(x) to be between 0 and a, for the variable x. (I do not want to restrict the plot, just the function - just as [in this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163746/how-to-restrict-the-domain-of-a-function)). `f[x_] := x*(1+a*ln(1-x/a))` , where `a` is a parameter, that I wish to vary from 0 to let's say 20 with increments of 0.05 for instance.

Then, I wish to plot the function with a slider for this `a` parameter, that is being able to vary it (hence the plot of f(x) - and its domain - adjusting dynamically).

Following the best answer [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1768636), I have tried this:

```
f[a_Real,x_Real]:= x*(1+a*ln(1-x/a))
Manipulate[Plot[f[a,x],{x,0,a}],{a,0,20,0.05}]
```

which doesn't work...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 2):

The problem: `ln(...)` should be `Log[...]`. Furthermore, the endpoints in `Plot` should be different, so you cannot use `a = 0`.

```
f[a_Real, x_Real] := x*(1 + a*Log[1 - x/a])
Manipulate[Plot[f[a, x], {x, 0, a}], {a, 0.05, 20, 0.05}]
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to also display the value of "a" on the graph, above the slider, or somewhere? When using the slider, I do not know know clearly what the value of "a" is (except observing the last x value on the axis...).

Comment: You can click on the "+" button next to the slider. Or you can use ``Manipulate[Plot[f[a, x], {x, 0, a}], {a, 0.05, 20, 0.05, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]``