# Find the range of a univariate function over a specific interval of the variable

Tags: functions, function-construction, conditional

I would like to find the range of the function below, but only for values of $a$ strictly greater than zero.

`v[a_]=-a*Log[1-(a - a E^(-1 - 1/a + ProductLog[E^(1 + 1/a)]))/a]`

In other words: what is the range of $v(a)$, for/conditional on $a>0$ (reals).

---

- I have tried this: (ie without restricting)
  `FunctionRange[v[a], a, y]`, but the computation time is too long, I can't manage to get an output.
- I also have tried to define the $v(a)$ function over the domain that interests me using this:

  `v[a_ /; 0 < a] := -a*Log[1-(a - a E^(-1 - 1/a + ProductLog[E^(1 + 1/a)]))/a]` (solution found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163746/how-to-restrict-the-domain-of-a-function)), and then `FunctionRange[v[a], a, y]`, but the computation time seems to bee stil too long. Probably due to the fact that my restricted definition doesn't seem to have worked: even in that case, `FunctionDomain[v[a],a]`returns $a≠0$ (instead of $a>0$ as I would have expected since it is what I defined in the first place).

EDIT

- This doesn't seem to work either: `Assuming[a>0,FunctionRange[v[a], a, y]]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
FunctionRange[{-a*
   Log[1 - (a - a E^(-1 - 1/a + ProductLog[E^(1 + 1/a)]))/a], 
  a > 0}, a, y]
```

> `5.14988*10^-9 <= y <= 0.5`

and warming message:

> Unable to find the exact range. Returning bounds on the range 
> computed using numeric optimization methods

So we have to consider `Derivative`

```
FunctionRange[{D[-a*
     Log[1 - (a - a E^(-1 - 1/a + ProductLog[E^(1 + 1/a)]))/a], a] // 
   Evaluate, a > 0}, a, y]
```

> `y > 0`

It means that `v[a]` is a monotonic function ! So we just need to calculate the `Limit` just as @Akku14 have done.

```
Limit[-a*Log[1 - (a - a E^(-1 - 1/a + ProductLog[E^(1 + 1/a)]))/a], 
 a -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]
Limit[-a*Log[1 - (a - a E^(-1 - 1/a + ProductLog[E^(1 + 1/a)]))/a], 
 a -> ∞]
```

> 0

> 1/2

Answer (score 3):

```
Limit[v[a], a -> 0, Direction -> -1]

(*   0   *)

Limit[v[a], a -> Infinity]

(*   1/2   *)

NMaximize[{v[a], a > 0}, a, WorkingPrecision -> 100]

(*   {0.4999999999999999999999999999999996695802781800686528047791793409305\
917941358131704720756957033359931, {a -> 
 1.89153358206810035345892896405454026939268176767953621670767804301\
 9662196519029316421185286618066641*10^32}}   *)

NMinimize[{v[a], a > 0}, a, WorkingPrecision -> 100]

(*   {9.2396091222066804246261095335668388330820970607385777570018055570761\
38791443783933838210621794192294*10^-7, {a -> 
 5.52917699540862549895289484183558798401702920323792264099048675666\
3524280963344309794142794231985742*10^-8}}   *)
```

Comment: `Series[-a*
  Log[1 - (a - a E^(-1 - 1/a + ProductLog[E^(1 + 1/a)]))/a], {a, 0, 
  2}, Assumptions -> a > 0]` results in $-a \log (a)+a^2 (\log (a)+1)+O\left(a^3\right)$, confirming positive values of `v[a]` and `Series[-a*Log[
   1 - (a - a E^(-1 - 1/a + ProductLog[E^(1 + 1/a)]))/a], {a, 
  Infinity, 2}]` results in $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{16 a}+\frac{1}{192 a^2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^3\right)$, confirming the inequality `v[a]<1/2` at `Infinity`.