# How to plot periodic functions that are defined over a specific region

Tags: plotting, functions

Let's say I've the following function (that is also periodic over the rest of the region I did not define):

$$
\begin{cases}
4\sin\left(2x\right)\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{when}\space0\le x<\pi\\
\\
4\exp\left(-2x\right)\space\space\space\space\space\text{when}\space\pi\le x<2\pi
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

So, after $2\pi$ the sine part of the function start again. How can I plot that function in Mathematica 10.0?

Comment: Use `Piecewise[{{4 Sin[2 x], Mod[x, 2 Pi] < Pi}}, 4 Exp[-2]]`.

Comment: Closely related [Can I limit PlotRange for 1 function in a Plot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7102/can-i-limit-plotrange-for-1-function-in-a-plot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is a bit bizarre, so I have modified it a bit to show its periodicity better:

```
Piecewise[{{Sin[x], Mod[x, 2 Pi] < \[Pi]}}, -Abs@Cos[x]]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Piecewise[{{Sin[x], Mod[x, 2 Pi] < \[Pi]}}, -Abs@Cos[x]], {x, -8, 8}]
```

[image]