# Restrict a curve to an intersection with another one

Tags: plotting, graphics, intersection

Code

```
p=0.5; r=0.1; x1=100; x2=10; x3=7;
Ec12R[N_] := x1 - x2 (1 + 2 N) + 2 (1 + N) N (1/p - 1) (1 + r)
Ec13R[N_] := x1 - x3 (1 + 2 N) + 2 (1 + N) N (1/p - 1) (1 + r)
Ed12R[N_] := x1 - x2
Es13R[N_] := Es13R[N_] := x1 - (1 + 2 N (1 + N))/(2 (1 + 2 N)) (x2 + x3) + (2 N^2 (1+r) (1/p - 1))/(1 + 2 N)
Plot[{Ed12R[N], Es13R[N], Ec13R[N], Ec12R[N]},
  {N, 1, 15},
  AxesLabel -> {"N", "E"},
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12},
  PlotRange -> {0, 100},
  AxesOrigin -> {1, 0},
  Ticks -> None
 ]
```

How can I restrict the yellow (`Ec13R[N]`) and green (`Ec12R[N]`) curve in a way that they do not continue after they intersect with red (`Es13R[N]`)? So I want to remove any value (of yellow and green) to the right of the intersection with red in the graph.

[image]

Comment: Please post code to reproduce the plot as well.

Comment: Please post your actual _Mathematica_ code. Without it no one will be able to see what you might have done wrong, nor will they be able to experiment with possible repairs.

Comment: not very general, but for starters, `Plot[{x, If[x^2 - 5 < x, x^2 - 5, Unevaluated@Sequence[]]}, {x, 0, 8}]`

Comment: I added the code, guys!

Comment: Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 8 Pi}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Abs[y] > 0.5]]

Comment: See [How do I plot a function over a subset of the displayed interval?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5858/how-do-i-plot-a-function-over-a-subset-of-the-displayed-interval)

Comment: @NiklasK. Please see your edited post for how to correctly format code blocks. In addition, `N` is reserved symbol in *Mathematica*. In general, it is a good idea not to use capitalized symbol names, since all built-in *Mathematica* functions begin with capital letters.

Comment: Defining anything with a capital letter in the beginning is begging for trouble. `N`, `E` and `I` have very specific meanings in Mma, and you might collide with a predefined name with mysterious results even on longer names. `N` happens to work in this case for very specific reasons, but you couldn't use it as a normal variable, for instance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ConditionalExpression`, which returns `Undefined` if the condition doesn't hold. `Plot` understands this, and doesn't try to plot anything on undefined values.

```
p = 0.5; r = 0.1; x1 = 100; x2 = 10; x3 = 7;
Ec12R[x_] := x1 - x2 (1 + 2 x) + 2 (1 + x) x (1/p - 1) (1 + r);
Ec13R[x_] := x1 - x3 (1 + 2 x) + 2 (1 + x) x (1/p - 1) (1 + r);
Ed12R[x_] := x1 - x2;
Es13R[x_] := 
  x1 - (1 + 2 x (1 + x))/(2 (1 + 2 x)) (x2 + 
      x3) + (2 x^2 (1 + r) (1/p - 1))/(1 + 2 x);

onlyBelow[eqn_, limit_] := ConditionalExpression[eqn, eqn < limit];

Plot[{Ed12R[x], Es13R[x], onlyBelow[Ec13R[x], Es13R[x]], 
  onlyBelow[Ec12R[x], Es13R[x]]}, {x, 1, 15}, AxesLabel -> {"N", "E"},
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12}, PlotRange -> {0, 100}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}, Ticks -> None]
```

[image]

Arbitrarily complicated constraints can be constructed if necessary. For instance:

```
beforeNextCrossing[f1_, limitf_, var_, firstval_] := 
  ConditionalExpression[f1[var], 
   var < Module[{x}, 
     Min[x /. Quiet@Solve[{f1[x] == limitf[x], x > firstval}, x]]]];

Plot[{Ed12R[x], Es13R[x], beforeNextCrossing[Ec13R, Es13R, x, 1], 
  beforeNextCrossing[Ec12R, Es13R, x, 1]}, {x, 1, 15}, 
 Evaluated -> True, AxesLabel -> {"N", "E"}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12}, PlotRange -> {0, 100}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}, Ticks -> None]
```

This produces the same result, but actually computes where the next crossing of plots occurs on `x` larger than 1. (Note that I added `Evaluated -> True` option. It forces `beforeNextCrossing` to be evaluated before plotting, instead of on every value of `x`.)

**EDIT**:

I want to refer to my recent answer ([How to find the next root larger than a specified value, numerically?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109076/3056)) featuring `findNextRoot` for a bit more robust method of finding a specific crossing like this. Using it, `beforeNextCrossing` can be written as:

```
beforeNextCrossing[f1_, limitf_, var_, firstval_] := 
 ConditionalExpression[f1[var], 
  var < (var /. First@findNextRoot[f1[var] == limitf[var], {var, firstval}])]
```