# How to find the next root larger than a specified value, numerically?

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

I would want to have a general-purpose, reasonably robust method of finding the next numerical root above a specific value of `x`. I'm stumped by the fact [`NArgMin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NArgMin.html) fails spectacularly even on this very simple example:

```
NArgMin[{x, x^2 - 1 == 0 && x > -1/2}, x, Reals]
```

> ```
> During evaluation of NArgMin::nosat: Obtained solution does not satisfy
>   the following constraints within Tolerance -> 0.001`: {1-x^2==0}. >>
> ```

```
(* -0.5 *)
```

Correct answer here is, of course, 1. All `Method`s seem to produce the same result. (I am actually a bit concerned it even produces a result, since it's very clearly wrong.) `FindRoot` isn't of help either, at least I can't understand how it would be.

Symbolic methods are, of course, "the solution" in this case. Problems with them arise when there are infinite amount of non-trivial roots, say in the case of `Sin[1 / (1 - x)] == x && x > 0`. Yet, on most of these cases location of the "next" root is almost glaringly obvious. How to solve this, preferably by not explicitly implementing a root-searching algorithm in own code?

Comment: Try `NMinimize[{x, x^2 - 1 == 0 && x > -1/2}, x, Method->"NonlinearInteriorPoint"]`. I realize this might not be documented. Alternatively use `FindMinimum` or `FindArgMin`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Please make this an answer! Why `FindMinimum` and `FindArgMin` work when `NArgMin` doesn't? Also, should it actually be considered a bug that `NArgMin` returns a value that clearly contradicts with specified constraints?

Comment: `NArgMin` should work with that `Method` option setting. As for the failure, I don't know the answer but will ask.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau `Method -> "NonlinearInteriorPoint"` seems to be the most robust approach to get an answer, and the intended root with couple other problematic cases I'm playing with.

Comment: `NArgMin[{x, Sin[1/(1 - x)] == x && x > 0.7}, x, 
 Method -> "NonlinearInteriorPoint"]` is a case where this method also fails, but maybe it's understandable to an extent.

Comment: Its important to realize none of these methods operate by first identifying the discrete space defined by your constraints. The "NonlinearInteriorPoint" method re-evaluates the objective function over 5000 times to get your solution.

Comment: @george2079 It would be great if there would be a way to do exactly that. :/

Comment: One relatively simple trick to find the root of `f[x]` for `x>y` could be to look for, say, the root of `f[x^2+y]` in the reals and return `y+x^2`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### `NDSolve` as an equation solver

[`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html) can search for the next root, using [`WhenEvent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent.html).

```
With[{f = x^2 - 2},
  NDSolve[{
    {y'[x] == D[f, x], y[x] == f /. x -> 1/2},
    WhenEvent[f == 0, x0 = x; "StopIntegration"]},
   {}, {x, 1/2, Infinity}]
  ];
x0
(*  1.41421  *)
```

By default `WhenEvent` does not find the root as accurately as possible, but it does a very good job:

```
x0^2 - 2
(*  -2.73115*10^-14  *)
```

#### Strengths and limitations

*Accuracy.*
`NDSolve`, since it uses local error estimates to control step size, is unlikely to skip a root.  It could happen in a DAE, if the underlying ODE allowed for large step sizes (it's not entirely clear to me how error estimation works in DAE, but I have observed step sizes too large for an accurate solution of the algebraic part of the system.)
The accuracy of the solution `x0` can be controlled through the `"LocationMethod"` option, or by post-processing with `FindRoot`.

*Multiple roots.*
Another issue is that `WhenEvent` detects roots by sign changes, so double roots would be missed.  These can be found by checking extrema or by checking when the value of the function is close to zero.

*Smooth functions.*
Dealing with differentiable functions is easier than with non-differentiable ones.  The approach above is unlikely to miss a zero-crossing. If the accumulation of numerical error is an issue, one can use the ["Projection" Method for NDSolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveProjection.html) to keep error drift in check.  For an even-multiple roots, one can check for extrema that are close enough to be zero to be considered zero. The ODE tends to become stiff near a multiple zero, so `Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"` may appropriate in this case.

*Non-differentiable and singular functions.*
Functions that don't have a derivative, such as `Abs`, cannot be integrated as above, because they cannot be evaluated numerically.  One can sometimes replace them with equivalents, such `Abs[x]` with `Sqrt[x^2]` for real `x`. Other functions, such as the cube root, have singularities that can give `NDSolve` trouble.  In some cases, `NDSolve` will either be insufficient or need extra help.

#### General function

The function `findNextRoot` (code below) returns a list of the next `n` roots (default 1).

```
findNextRoot[
 eqn,          (* equation to be solved, or function whose next root is sought *)
 {var,         (* the variable on which eqn depends *)
  val,         (* starting value for search *)
  v2},         (* optional: upper limit for search; default = Infinity *)
 n,            (* optional: max. number of roots to seek; default = 1 *)
 opts          (* options *)
 ]
```

Options and their defaults:

```
Direction -> 1,               (* direction of search *)
"ZeroTolerance" -> Automatic, (* if residual is less, then a possible zero *)
"PostProcess" -> None,        (* function to apply, e.g., FindRoot *)
"WhenEventOptions" ->         (* options to pass to WhenEvent *)
  {"LocationMethod" -> {"Brent", AccuracyGoal -> 4, PrecisionGoal -> 4}},
"NDSolveOptions" -> {}}       (* options to pass to NDSolve *)
```

For differentiable functions, `"ZeroTolerance"` is `10^-8`; otherwise it is `10^-6`.  There are two events, one to detect simple crossings and one to detect multiple roots (or non-sign-change zeros).  In my (perhaps limited) experience, it is better to post-process with `FindRoot` than to use it through `WhenEvent`.

*Examples*

```
findNextRoot[x^2 - 2 == 0, {x, 1/2}]
(*  {{x -> 1.41421}}  *)
```

Find a root in the other direction:

```
findNextRoot[x^2 - 2 == 0, {x, 1/2}, Direction -> -1]
(*  {{x -> -1.41421}}  *)
```

Find up to 15 roots on the interval `1/2 < x < 20` (there are only six):

```
findNextRoot[Sin[x] == 0, {x, 1/2, 20}, 15]
(*
  {{x -> 3.14159}, {x -> 6.28319}, {x -> 9.42478},
   {x -> 12.5664}, {x -> 15.708},  {x -> 18.8496}}
*)
```

Find the next 15 roots:

```
findNextRoot[Sin[x] == 0, {x, 1/2}, 15]
(*
  {{x -> 3.14159}, {x -> 6.28319}, {x -> 9.42478},
   {x -> 12.5664}, {x -> 15.708},  {x -> 18.8496}, {x -> 21.9911},
   {x -> 25.1327}, {x -> 28.2743}, {x -> 31.4159}, {x -> 34.5575},
   {x -> 37.6991}, {x -> 40.8407}, {x -> 43.9823}, {x -> 47.1239}}
*)
```

Find multiple roots of `Cos[x]^6 == 1`.  This requires some tweaking. In particular `"StiffnessSwitching"` and post-processing by `FindRoot`.  Note that this equation has the same solutions as the previous example `Sin[x] == 0` and that `NSolve` cannot solve the multiple-root equation (although `Solve` can).

```
(sol = findNextRoot[Cos[x]^6 == 1, {x, 1.5, 50}, 20
   , "ZeroTolerance" -> 1*^-6
   , "PostProcess" -> FindRoot
   , "WhenEventOptions" -> {"DetectionMethod" -> "DerivativeSign"}
   , "NDSolveOptions" -> {Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
      PrecisionGoal -> 10, AccuracyGoal -> 10}]) // AbsoluteTiming
NSolve[Sin[x] == 0 && 1.5 < x < 50, x] // AbsoluteTiming
NSolve[Cos[x]^6 == 1 && 1.5 < x < 50, x] // AbsoluteTiming
(*
  {0.029014, {{x -> 3.14159}, ..., {x -> 47.1239}}}
  {0.048492, {{x -> 3.14159}, ..., {x -> 47.1239}}}
  {0.085889, {}}
*)

Cos[x]^6 - 1 /. sol
(*  {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}  *)
```

Five points of intersection:

```
sols = findNextRoot[Sin[x] == 0.4 Cos[10 Sqrt[2] x], {x, 2}, 5]

Plot[{Sin[x], 0.4 Cos[10 Sqrt[2] x]}, {x, 2., 8.}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[{x, Sin[x]} /. sols]}]

(*  {{x -> 3.02062}, {x -> 3.23834}, {x -> 3.39528}, {x -> 5.9535}, {x -> 6.06944}}  *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Non-differentiable case.  Here the problem `FindRoot` faces is that starting below `Sqrt[2]` leads to trouble while starting above does not.

```
findNextRoot[Abs[x - Sqrt[2]], {x, 1/2}(*,"ZeroTolerance"\[Rule]2*10^-8*)]
Abs[x - Sqrt[2]] /. %

findNextRoot[Abs[x - Sqrt[2]], {x, 1/2}, "ZeroTolerance" -> 2*10^-8]
Abs[x - Sqrt[2]] /. %
```

> FindRoot::lstol: The line search...was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function.

```
(*
{{x -> 1.41421}}
{9.32587*10^-15}
{{x -> 1.41421}}
{2.22045*10^-16}
*)
```

You can verify with

```
FindRoot[Abs[x - Sqrt[2]], {x, Sqrt[2] - 1.*^-14}]
FindRoot[Abs[x - Sqrt[2]], {x, Sqrt[2] + 1.*^-14}]
```

Another non-differential case:

```
findNextRoot[Abs[Cos[x]] == 0, {x, 1/2}, 3]
(*  {{x -> 1.5708}, {x -> 4.71239}, {x -> 7.85398}}  *)
```

#### Code dump

The approach in `findNextRoot[]` is to determine whether the derivative of the residual function can be evaluated and then to set up an appropriate system.  I say the function is "differentiable" when it can be evaluated.  The two principle workhorses are `NDSolve` and `WhenEvent`, so the ability to pass options to them is provided via the options `"NDSolveOptions"` and `"WhenEventOptions"`.  In the non-differentiable case, `FindRoot` is sometimes called; one might want to add a way to pass options to it, too.

The function that constructs the system for `NDSolve` is `getSysOpts`.
The system it constructs needs to be in terms of the local `Module` variables used in the `NDSolve` call.
These could be passed as arguments, which would add ten more arguments to `getSysOpts`; or they could be localized as private symbols in a package context.
Instead I adapted the method in
[NDSolve Method Plugin Framework](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolvePlugIns.html), in which string tokens represent the variables of the system.
The tokens in the code returned by `getSysOpts` are replaced by local variables before passing it to `NDSolve`.

The string tokens represent the following variables:

```
"X"    (* dependent variable                                                *) 
"T"    (* independent variable (for time integration)                       *)
"F"    (* the function whose root is to be found                            *)
"FP"   (* the derivative of "F"                                             *)
"XDAE" (* dependent variable for DAE integration                            *) 
"T0"   (* initial value of "T"                                              *) 
"T1"   (* temporary variable for storing result of FindRoot (non-diff case) *)  
"T2"   (* dummy symbolic variable for FindRoot (non-diff case)              *)
"CNT"  (* counts number of roots found so far                               *)
"MAX"  (* maximum number of roots to find                                   *)
```

The basic systems for integration are

```
{"X"'["T"] == "FP", "X"["T0"] == "F" /. "T" -> "T0"}          (* diff case *)
{"X"["T"] == "F", "XDAE"'["T"] == "F", "XDAE"["T0"] == "T0"}  (* non-diff case *)
```

In both cases `"X"` is integrated to be the residual function `"F"`.
In the DAE system, `"XDAE"` is the integral of `"F"`.  The hope here is that `NDSolve` will better track the features of `"F"`.  The alternative `"XDAE"'["T"} == 1` tends to be faster, but the larger step sizes sometimes miss roots.

The strategies for root-finding are the following events:

```
TYPE OF ROOT                 DIFF CASE       NON-DIFF CASE
Sign change (oddroot):       "F" == 0        "F" == 0
No sign change (evenroot):   "FP" == 0       Abs["X"["T"]] < tol
```

The no-sign-change case is tricky.  In each case, further processing is required. In the differentiable case, one is detecting all the local extrema, so one has to check whether they are close enough to zero be considered zero.  In the non-differentiable case, one cannot use the derivative, so one can only check when the function gets close to zero, and then search for a zero.  What is considered "close" is given by the value of the option `"ZeroTolerance"`.  This has limitations, of course.  Basic numerical difficulties aside, one particular one is that there seems to be no easy way to bracket the root, so that `FindRoot` does not go on a wild goose chase. The expression for `"ZeroTolerance"` may be given in terms of `NDSolve` variables `"T"`, `"X"`, `"F"` and so forth and the appropriate localized variables. For example:

```
findNextRoot[Abs[Exp[-x] Sin[x]] Cos[x], {x, Pi/3}, 15, 
 "ZeroTolerance" -> 10^-1 Exp[-"T"]]
```

The variable `x` may be used instead of `"T"` here because `"T"` represents the variable passed.  Overall, however, one should expect difficult cases to be rare and to require special attention by the user.

Note: The event `oddroot` in the non-differentiable case is often superseded by the criterion in `evenroot`: the residual will be less than the tolerance before it crosses zero, unless (1) the step size is large enough that the residual is not less than the tolerance or (2) the function remains below the tolerance.  There might be a better design.

Full code:

```
ClearAll[findNextRoot, iFindNextRoot, getSysOpts];
Options[findNextRoot] = Options[iFindNextRoot] =
   {Direction -> 1,
    "ZeroTolerance" -> Automatic, (* if residual is less, then a possible zero *)
    "PostProcess" -> None,  (* function to apply, e.g., FindRoot *)
    "WhenEventOptions" -> {"LocationMethod" -> {"Brent", 
        AccuracyGoal -> 4, PrecisionGoal -> 4}},
    "NDSolveOptions" -> {}};

getSysOpts[differentiable_, opts_] := getSysOpts[differentiable,
  OptionValue[findNextRoot, opts, "ZeroTolerance"],
  OptionValue[findNextRoot, opts, "WhenEventOptions"],
  OptionValue[findNextRoot, opts, "NDSolveOptions"]]

(* differentiable f *)
getSysOpts[True, tol0_, eventopts_, ndsolveopts_] :=
  Module[{oddroot, evenroot, ode, ndsolveopts2},
   With[{tol = tol0 /. Automatic -> 1*^-8},
    ode = Hold@{"X"'["T"] == "FP", "X"["T0"] == "F" /. "T" -> "T0"};
    oddroot = WhenEvent["F" == 0,
      "CNT"++; Sow["T", "iFindNextRoot"];
      If["CNT" >= "MAX", "StopIntegration", {}],    (* found all: done *)
      eventopts];
    evenroot = WhenEvent["FP" == 0,
      If[Abs["X"["T"]] < tol,                       (* close enough to be a zero? *)
       "CNT"++; Sow["T", "iFindNextRoot"];
       If["CNT" >= "MAX", "StopIntegration", {}],   (* found all: done *)
       {}],
      eventopts];
    ndsolveopts2 = Join[ndsolveopts,
      {Method -> {"Projection",
                  "Invariants" -> {"X"["T"] == "F"},
                  Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"}}]];
   {{ode, oddroot, evenroot}, ndsolveopts2}];

(* non-differentiable f *)
getSysOpts[False, tol0_, eventopts_, ndsolveopts_] :=
  Module[{oddroot, evenroot, ode},
   With[{tol = tol0 /. Automatic -> 10^-6},
    ode = Hold@{"X"["T"] == "F", "XDAE"'["T"] == "F", "XDAE"["T0"] == "T0"};
    oddroot = Hold@With[{f1 = "F" /. "T" -> "T2"},
       WhenEvent["F" == 0,
        "CNT"++; Sow["T", "iFindNextRoot"];
        If["CNT" >= "MAX", "StopIntegration", {}],   (* found all: done *)
        eventopts]];
    evenroot = Hold@With[{f1 = "F" /. "T" -> "T2"},
       WhenEvent[Abs["X"["T"]] < tol,                (* close to root? *)
        "T1" = "T2" /. FindRoot[f1, {"T2", "T"}];    (* search *)
        If[NumberQ["T1"],                            (* search succeeded? *)
         "CNT"++; Sow["T1", "iFindNextRoot"];
         If["CNT" >= "MAX", "StopIntegration", {}],  (* found all: done *)
         {}],
        eventopts]]];
   {{ode, oddroot, evenroot}, ndsolveopts}];

iFindNextRoot[f_, d_, n_, {var_, val_, v2_: Automatic}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Module[{vtmp, var2, y, daeY, diffQ, nfound, roots,
    sys, ndsolveopts, localize, post, dir},
   dir = Sign[OptionValue[Direction]];
   diffQ = NumberQ[d /. var -> N@val]; (* differentiable Q *)
   localize = # /. {"X" -> y, "T" -> var, "F" -> f, "FP" -> d, "XDAE" -> daeY, 
       "T0" -> val, "T1" -> vtmp, "T2" -> var2, "CNT" -> nfound, "MAX" -> n} &;
   {sys, ndsolveopts} = ReleaseHold@ localize@ getSysOpts[diffQ, {opts}];
   nfound = 0;
   roots = Last@ Reap[
      NDSolve[sys, {}, {var, val, v2 /. Automatic :> dir*Infinity}, ndsolveopts],
      "iFindNextRoot"] /. {r_List} :> r;
   post = OptionValue["PostProcess"] /. 
     Automatic | None -> ({First[#2] -> Last[#2]} &);
   post[f, {var, #}] & /@ roots
   ];

findNextRoot[eqn_, {var_, val_, v2_: Automatic}, n_Integer: 1, 
   opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  With[{dir = Sign[OptionValue[Direction]],
    f = eqn /. Equal -> Subtract},
   iFindNextRoot[
     f,           (* objective function *)
     D[f, var],   (* Jacobian *)
     n,           (* (max) number of roots to find *)
     {var, val, v2}, opts] /; Abs@dir == 1];
```

Comment: This is cool and probably closest to using mechanics which make most sense for the problem at hand, although I wished a bit less code would be sufficient. It takes a while to understand! :)

Comment: @kirma Thanks.  I'll add some explanation later.  I just ran out of time. `getSysOpts` returns pseudo-code that is converted into actual code via `localize`.  I used some of the same string names as ``NDSolve`SolutionDataComponent`` (see http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html, http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolvePlugIns.html) in the hopes that it would be familiar to some.  Of course I had to add some variables.  Another approach would be to share variables between the function in a package.

Comment: @kirma Updated with explanation and slight improvements to code.

Answer (score 7):

`NSolve` is pretty robust

```
eqn1 = x^2 - 1 == 0;

soln1 = NSolve[{eqn1, x > -1/2}, x, Reals][[1]]

(*  {x -> 1.}  *)

eqn1 /. soln1

(*  True  *)

eqn2 = Sin[1/(1 - x)] == x;

OrderedQ[x /. NSolve[{eqn2, x > 0}, x, Reals]] // Quiet

(*  True  *)
```

Since the roots are ordered, just take the first

```
soln2 = NSolve[{eqn2, x > 0}, x, Reals][[1]] // Quiet

(*  {x -> 0.599745}  *)

eqn2 /. soln2

(*  True  *)

Plot[{Sin[1/(1 - x)], x}, {x, 0, 0.95},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[5],
   Point[{x, x} /. soln2]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't remember `NSolve` can return a partial set like that! Now I wonder how it judges how many solutions to list on a non-complete set...

Comment: Amusingly this approach breaks down with roots like `Sin[x] == 1/2`. Quick workaround for this case is `Min @@ ((x /. NSolve[{Sin[x] == 1/2, x > 0}, x, Reals]) /. ConditionalExpression[v_, c_] :> MinValue[{v, c}, Union@Cases[c, C[_], \[Infinity]]])` - are there more robust methods?

Comment: ... and now that I think of it, periodic roots were the reason why I didn't use `NSolve` in the first place. Maybe it's still the least problematic option.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if this is a bug or just goes with the territory when doing constrained optimization; my guess is the latter. Workarounds include using
`FindArgMin`, which has fewer method coices and basically is forced to use one that works, or to specify a nondefault `Method` for `NArgMin`. Below we see that either of these will behave better on this problem.

```
In[196]:= NArgMin[{x, x^2 - 1 == 0 && x > -1/2}, x, 
 Method -> "NonlinearInteriorPoint"]

Out[196]= 0.999999992549

In[198]:= FindArgMin[{x, x^2 - 1 == 0 && x > -1/2}, x]

Out[198]= {1.}
```

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by @BobHanlon's answer and `FindRoot`, I developed my own `findNextRoot`:

```
ClearAll[findNextRoot];

Options[findNextRoot] = {Direction -> 1};

findNextRoot[eqn_, {var_, val_}, OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Module[{select, compare, findvalue, sol},
  {select, compare, findvalue} =
   If[OptionValue[Direction] >= 0,
    {Min, Greater, NMinValue}, {Max, Less, NMaxValue}];
  sol = NSolve[{eqn, compare[var, val]}, var, Reals];
  (((var /. # & /@ sol) /. 
       ConditionalExpression[v_, c_] :> 
        Root[{Function[var, eqn /. Equal -> Subtract], 
          findvalue[{v, c}, 
           Union@Cases[c, 
             C[_], \[Infinity]]]}]) /. {nonempty__} :> {var -> 
        select[nonempty]}) /; Head@sol === List]
```

It works for (rational) polynomials with starting points of "wrong" slope:

```
With[{eq1 = x^2, eq2 = 1},
 Plot[{eq1, eq2}, {x, -2, 2}, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize@Large, 
    Point[{x, eq1}] /. findNextRoot[eq1 == eq2, {x, -1/2}]}]]
```

[image]

```
With[{eq1 = (-15 + 2 x (-104 + x (-93 + 22 x)))/
     (10 + 20 x), eq2 = 0},
 Plot[{eq1, eq2}, {x, -2, 6}, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize@Large, 
    Point[{x, eq1}] /. findNextRoot[eq1 == eq2, {x, 1}]}]]
```

[image]

With `Direction`, one can also search roots backwards:

```
With[{eq1 = (-15 + 2 x (-104 + x (-93 + 22 x)))/
     (10 + 20 x), eq2 = 0},
 Plot[{eq1, eq2}, {x, -2, 6}, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize@Large, 
    Point[{x, eq1}] /. 
     findNextRoot[eq1 == eq2, {x, 1}, Direction -> -1]}]]
```

[image]

Cyclic roots are also handled gracefully:

```
With[{eq1 = Sin[x], eq2 = 1/2},
 Plot[{eq1, eq2}, {x, 0, 2}, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize@Large, 
    Point[{x, eq1}] /. findNextRoot[eq1 == eq2, {x, 0}]}]]
```

[image]

... and an infinite amount of untrivial roots:

```
With[{eq1 = Sin[1/(1 - x)], eq2 = x},
 Plot[{eq1, eq2}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize@Large, 
    Point[{x, eq1}] /. findNextRoot[eq1 == eq2, {x, 0}]}]]
```

[image]

```
With[{eq1 = x Sin[1/x], eq2 = x/2}, 
 Plot[{eq1, eq2}, {x, -1, 1}, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize@Large, 
    Point[{x, eq1}] /. 
     findNextRoot[eq1 == eq2, {x, 1/3}, Direction -> -1]}]]
```

[image]

When no root is found, empty set is returned like in the case of `FindRoot`:

```
findNextRoot[x == 1, {x, 2}]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

This version seems to also work equally well using either `NSolve` or `Solve`. With `Solve`, one can get nice symbolic `Root`s.

Comment: Counterexamples to these succeeding roots are welcome.

Comment: One counterexample is essentially the same as `Solve[Sin[1/(1 - E^(1 - x))] == 1 - x && x > 0, x, Reals]`, for which (`N`)`Solve` seems to fail to find a root.

Comment: use an interval: `NSolve[Sin[1/(1 - E^(1 - x))] == 1 - x && 0 < x < 0.99, x][[1]]`