# Roots of a characteristic equation. Can Mathematica solve it?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I have been using *Mathematica* for a few years, but with basic things. Now I need to find the first 10 roots of the following equation:

```
Cos[y] - 2 E^(-y)/(1 + E^(-2 y)) == 0
```

I have been trying to use the commands `Solve`, `SolveAlways` and `FindRoot`. But the only one that worked is the last one, but it needs a value near the root.
Could you help me?

Comment: What's wrong with `FindRoot[Cos[y] - 2 E^(-y)/(1 + E^(-2 y)), {y, 1}]`?

Comment: Note that `2 E^(-y)/(1 + E^(-2 y))` is the same as `Sech[y]`.

Comment: In particular, since the hyperbolic secant goes to zero very rapidly as $y \to \infty$, the roots (except perhaps for the first few) are going to be very very close to half-integer multiples of $\pi$.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109012/how-to-find-the-next-root-larger-than-a-specified-value-numerically

Answer (score 8):

`NDSolve[ ]` allows a fine grained search for events through the interval by using the clause `WhenEvent[ ]`.
Here we use it to find the roots and to stop searching when ten roots have been found.

`Sow[ ]`and `Reap[ ]`are used to collect our findings.

```
dy = D[Cos[x] - 2 E^(-x)/(1 + E^(-2 x)), x];
sol = Reap@ NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == dy, y[0] == 0, a[0] == 0, 
                         WhenEvent[y[x] == 0, {a[x] -> a[x] + 1, Sow[x]}],
                         WhenEvent[a[x] == 10, {tf = x, "StopIntegration"}]}, 
                         y, {x, 0, 33}, DiscreteVariables -> {a}
                         ];
Plot[sol[[1]][t], {t, 0, tf}, 
     Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[Thread[{sol[[2, 1]], 0}]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Not a solution I would have thought of, but I suppose it does the trick!  Also note that `sol[[2,1]] / Pi` yields `{1.50562, 2.49975, 3.50001, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5, 10.5}` (see my comment on the original question.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Yep, you're right of course and that was my first approach. I changed it because Runny posted his answer a few seconds before me and I thought this one is a "classic" approach

Answer (score 7):

Exploiting Michael's observation in the comments, we can use the somewhat regular root spacing along with the [Delves-Lyness method](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-1967-0228165-4) to locate the roots precisely:

```
Table[Re[NIntegrate[# (Sech[#] Tanh[#] - Sin[#])/(Cos[#] - Sech[#]) &[
                    π (k + 1/2) + π Exp[I t]/4] Exp[I t], {t, -π, π},
                    Method -> {"Trapezoidal", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]]/8,
      {k, 10}]
   {4.730040744862704, 7.853204624095836, 10.995607838001671, 14.137165491257463,
    17.27875965739948, 20.420352245626063, 23.56194490204045, 26.703537555508188,
    29.845130209103246, 32.98672286269282}
```

If more digits are needed, these can then be fed to `Root[]` for refinement, like so:

```
N[Root[{Cos[#] - Sech[#] &, #}] & /@ %, 25]
   {4.730040744862704026024048, 7.853204624095837556477067,
    10.99560783800167090666903, 14.13716549125746417710592,
    17.27875965739948143809107, 20.42035224562606109093641,
    23.56194490204045507539202, 26.70353755550818624841941,
    29.84513020910325426700149, 32.98672286269281956154720}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `findNextRoot` from my answer to [How to find the next root larger than a specified value, numerically?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109012/how-to-find-the-next-root-larger-than-a-specified-value-numerically/109276#109276)...

I'm not sure if the "first ten roots" starts includes `0` or just positive roots.  The function `findNextRoot` uses `NDSolve`, like Dr. belisarius's answer, and the stiffness at `y == 0` is an issue for the `"Projection"` method that `findNextRoot` uses by default as well as for `FindRoot`.

```
findNextRoot[Cos[y] - 2 E^(-y)/(1 + E^(-2 y)) == 0, {y, 0}, 10,
 "NDSolveOptions" -> {Method -> Automatic}]
(*
  {{y -> 4.73004}, {y -> 7.8532}, {y -> 10.9956}, {y -> 14.1372},
   {y -> 17.2788}, {y -> 20.4204}, {y -> 23.5619}, {y -> 26.7035},
   {y -> 29.8451}, {y -> 32.9867}}
*)
```

Including zero:

```
findNextRoot[Cos[y] - 2 E^(-y)/(1 + E^(-2 y)) == 0, {y, -1/10}, 10,
 "NDSolveOptions" -> {Method -> Automatic}]
(*
  {{y -> 0.0000245925}, {y -> 4.73004}, {y -> 7.8532},
   {y -> 10.9956}, {y -> 14.1372}, {y -> 17.2788}, {y -> 20.4204},
   {y -> 23.5619}, {y -> 26.7035}, {y -> 29.8451}}
*)
```

Should one feel that the root at `y == 0` is not accurate enough, observe that `Cos[0]` is `1`, so at machine precision a residual of `$MachineEpsilon` is pretty good:

```
Cos[y] - 2 E^(-y)/(1 + E^(-2 y)) /. %
(*
  {1.11022*10^-16, 1.41603*10^-9, 4.49942*10^-10, -1.46555*10^-7, -9.86477*10^-8,
   -4.52107*10^-8, 5.93708*10^-7, 2.04556*10^-7, -2.59637*10^-10, 4.35094*10^-9}
*)
```

The residuals at the other roots are explained by the default `AccuracyGoal` of `FindRoot` being `8`.  Compare:

```
findNextRoot[Cos[y] - 2 E^(-y)/(1 + E^(-2 y)) == 0,
 {y, -1/10}, 10,
 "NDSolveOptions" -> {Method -> Automatic},
 "PostProcess" -> (FindRoot[##, AccuracyGoal -> 12] &)]
Cos[y] - 2 E^(-y)/(1 + E^(-2 y)) /. %
(*
  {{y -> 0.0000589511}, {y -> 4.73004}, {y -> 7.8532}, {y -> 10.9956},
   {y -> 14.1372}, {y -> 17.2788}, {y -> 20.4204}, {y -> 23.5619},
   {y -> 26.7035}, {y -> 29.8451}}

  {0., -2.67147*10^-16, -4.14382*10^-16, 3.90326*10^-16, -2.89806*10^-16,
   -1.71698*10^-15, 1.76219*10^-15, 1.43247*10^-16, -1.50236*10^-15, -1.17313*10^-15}
*)
```

Answer (score 4):

Basically the question is about using `Solve` as the most straightforward tool for finding **exact solutions** however all the other existing answers demonstrate numerical techniques and find **approximate solutions**.  It was observed in the comments that `2 E^(-y)/(1 + E^(-2 y)) == Sech[y] == 1/Cosh[y]`.    As `Cosh[y]` is an exponentially increasing function it is obvious that there are infinitely many solutions of the given equations very close to those of this trivial equation `Cos[y] == 0`.  `Solve` will not give any solutions unless it is suplemented by an appropriate codition restricting the space of solutions to a finite number of them. There were many asnwers discussing this issue and it is easy to find them on this site. The exact solutions of transcendental equations in *Mathematica* are given in terms of the `Root` objects since the *version 7*, see e.g. this post by
Roger Germundsson 
[Mathematica 7, Johannes Kepler, and Transcendental Roots](http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/12/18/mathematica-7-johannes-kepler-and-transcendental-roots/).

Since we would like to find the first `10` solutions and having said the remarks above we conclude that the condition supplementing the equation should be roughly `0 <= y <= 10 Pi` but to be ensured one can put `0 <= y <= 11 Pi`.

Now we can use `Solve` as well as `Reduce`, e.g.

```
sols = DeleteDuplicates[ y /. Solve[ Cos[y] - 2 E^(-y)/(1 + E^(-2 y)) == 0 
                                     && 0 <= y <= 35, y]];
```

We have used `DeleteDuplicates` because `Solve` produces four copies of the same solution for `y == 0`. In fact we have obtained all the desired solutions:

```
Length @ sols
```

> ```
>  11
> ```

All the above is true if we asume we need only real roots. However if we are to find all complex solutions we need to do it this way:

```
solComp = ReIm[y]/.{ ToRules @ Reduce[ Cos[y] - 2 E^(-y)/(1 + E^(-2 y)) == 0
                                     && 0 <= Abs[y] <= 12, y]};

ContourPlot[
 { Re[Cos[x + I y] - 2 E^(-x - I y)/(1 + E^(-2 (x + I y)))],
   Im[Cos[x + I y] - 2 E^(-x - I y)/(1 + E^(-2 (x + I y)))]},
 {x, -11, 11}, {y, -11, 11}, 
 PlotPoints -> 75, MaxRecursion -> 5,  
 Epilog -> {Table[{Dashed, Gray, Circle[{0, 0}, i]}, {i, sols[[2;;4]]}],
            Red, PointSize[0.015], Point[solComp]}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", Bottom]]
```

[image]

This plot sheds some light why `Solve` finds **four copies of trivial solution** `z == x + I y == 0`.  Moreover we can find that on the both axes roots are in equal distances from the origin exchanging `x` and `y` because the equation is equivalent to `Cos[x + I y] ==  1/Cosh[x + I y]` and `{Cos[I y], Cosh[I y]}` yields `{Cosh[y], Cos[y]}` i.e. they exchange their roles. However on the level of the given function `1/Cosh[x + I y]` becomes `1/Cos[y]` for `x == 0` and this is why there occurs a singularity when `Cos[y] == 0`.

```
Reduce[Cosh[x + I y] == 0 && -(1/4) < x < 1/4 && 5/4 < y < 7/4, {x, y}]
```

> ```
>    x == 0 && y == Pi/2
> ```

This is a the first singular point of `Sech[ x + I y]`.

In case of more sophisticated equations one should plot given functions to estimate the range `0 <= y <= yMax`.  Let's plot the first `10` real and positive roots:

```
Plot[ Cos[y] - 2 E^(-y)/(1 + E^(-2 y)), {y, 0, 35}, 
      Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[Tuples[{sols, {0}}]]}]
```

[image]

Approximate values of `y` one finds with

```
N @ sols
```

> ```
> { 0., 4.73004, 7.8532, 10.9956, 14.1372, 17.2788, 20.4204,
>   23.5619, 26.7035, 29.8451, 32.9867}
> ```

and as I pointed out earlier differences between consecutive roots tend to `Pi`:

```
Differences @ %
```

> ```
>  { 4.73004, 3.12316, 3.1424, 3.14156, 3.14159, 3.14159, 3.14159,
>    3.14159, 3.14159, 3.14159}
> ```

quite rapidly, what give us an estimation for the condition `0 <= y <= yMax` to find much more exact solutions.

Here we demonstrate the structure of contours `{Re[f[z]==0, Im[f[z]==0}` near the first singular point on the imaginary axis.

```
cp = ContourPlot[
 { Re[Cos[x + I y] - 2 E^(-x - I y)/(1 + E^(-2 (x + I y)))] == 0, 
   Im[Cos[x + I y] - 2 E^(-x - I y)/(1 + E^(-2 (x + I y)))] == 0},
 {x, -2.2, 2.2}, {y, -2.2, 2.2}, ContourStyle -> {Orange, Green}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.015], Point[solComp]}, PlotPoints -> 75, 
 MaxRecursion -> 5];

GraphicsRow[ 
 Table[ Show[ 
  ContourPlot[{ f[Cos[x + I y] - 2 E^(-x - I y)/(1 + E^(-2 (x + I y)))]},
    {x, -2.2, 2.2}, {y, -2.2, 2.2}, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 5, 
    ColorFunction -> ColorData["DeepSeaColors"]], cp], {f, {Re, Im}}]]
```

[image]

Althought the green and orange lines intersect, there is no root since a singular point does not belong to the domain of the underlying function.

Answer (score 3):

How about [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html)?

```
NSolve[Cos[y] - 2 E^(-y)/(1 + E^(-2 y)) == 0 && 0 < y < 11 Pi, y]
(*
{{y -> 4.73004}, {y -> 7.8532}, {y -> 10.9956}, {y -> 14.1372},
 {y -> 17.2788}, {y -> 20.4204}, {y -> 23.5619}, {y -> 26.7035},
 {y -> 29.8451}, {y -> 32.9867}}
*)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following should give you about 10 roots of the equation:

```
FindRoot[Cos[y] - 2 E^(-y)/(1 + E^(-2 y)), {y, #}] & /@ Range[0, 30, 3]

(* {{y -> 0.}, {y -> -23.5619}, {y -> 4.73004}, {y -> 7.8532}, {y -> 
   10.9956}, {y -> 14.1372}, {y -> 17.2788}, {y -> 20.4204}, {y -> 
   23.5619}, {y -> 26.7035}, {y -> 29.8451}} *)
```