# Nintegrate until a certain value is reached

Tags: numerical-integration

I need to launch a `Nintegrate` command to integrate a function on a domain $(0,x_{b})$ where the value $x_{b}$ is determined by the fact that the integral reach a certain value. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find the value of $x_{b}$ by using `NDSolve` and a stopping condition:

```
Reap[
  NDSolve[{x'[t] == Sin[t], x[0] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[x[t] == 1, Sow[t]; "StopIntegration"]}, 
   x, {t, Infinity}]][[2, 1, 1]]

(* 1.5708 *)
```

Just to verify:

```
Integrate[Sin[t], {t, 0, 1.5708}]

(* 1. *)
```

Comment: This answer was clearly inspired by @MichaelE2 's answer (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109276/3056) to my earlier question, although I didn't remember this while writing my own...