# Integrate function in segments of defined area (and get borders)

Tags: numerical-integration, event-detection

I have to integrate a function and need to split the area under the function in segments of equal area. Of all the areas I get, I need the values of the borders on the x axis.

I found an approach with `NDSolve` and `WhenEvent` to specify 
the area size ([Nintegrate until a certain value is reached](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114568/nintegrate-until-a-certain-value-is-reached/114579)). However, I don't get it to work. For simplicity, my function I want to integrate is simply a straight line. I used an interpolating function to get the function of the straight line, because eventually I will also come from discrete points and have to fit a more complicated function.
Here is what I have so far:

```
timeVector = Table[x, {x, 0, 99}];
yVector = Table[2.5, {100}];(*my function*)
xy = {timeVector, yVector} // Transpose;
interpol = Interpolation[xy];
desiredArea=20;

(*here the actual problem*)

Reap[NDSolve[{x'[t]==interpol[t],x[0]==0, 
   WhenEvent[Integrate[interpol[t] == desiredArea, Sow[t]], 
    "StopIntegration"]}, t, {t,0,99}]]
```

How can I make the `WhenEvent` function detect multiples of the area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```
Reap[NDSolve[{
   x'[t] == interpol[t], x[0] == 0,
   mark[0] == desiredArea,
   WhenEvent[x[t] == mark[t], Sow[t]; 
    mark[t] -> mark[t] + desiredArea]}, x, {t, 0, 99}, 
  DiscreteVariables -> {mark}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Since `x[t]` will be the integral of `interpol[t]` from `0` up tp `t`, we just need to set a mark for the next time the area increases by `desiredArea` every time the mark is reached.  Note that the interval at the end (`{96, 99}` in the example) will have an area less than or equal to `desiredArea`.

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for. Just did not think of the substitution of x[t] ==mark[t] in the WhenEvent.

Comment: @Niki You're welcome.