# How do you plot the same function with different options over different intervals?

Tags: plotting, legending

Here is the motivation for my question. I want to plot `Sin[x]` over the interval `0` to `2 π`, with the part from `π/2` to `2 π` as a dashed curve. I want to plot this with a legend so that it shows the solid part is for acute angles, and the dashed part is for, say, other angles. Perhaps using `Show` and `ShowLegend` will work, but I couldn't figure out how to get the legend boxes to match the curves (solid and dashed curves). It seems `PlotLegend` takes care of this for you, but I couldn't figure out how to use this in `Show`. So I thought using `PlotLegend` in `Plot` will be easiest, except I don't know how to use `Plot` for the same function with different options on different intervals.

I tried using the suggestions from [Plotting piecewise function with distinct colors in each section](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1128/plotting-piecewise-function-with-distinct-colors-in-each-section), but I think my problem is that the same function is being used for both parts of the piecewise function I defined.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something like :

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]

Plot[{Piecewise[{{Sin[x], 0 <= x <= \[Pi]/2}}, 0], Piecewise[{{Sin[x], \[Pi]/2 <= x <= 2 \[Pi]}}, 0]}, {x, 0,  2 \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashed},PlotLegend -> {"Acute angles", "Other angles"}]
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks. This helps but I see on the x axis the dashed curve from 0 to pi/2, although it is not easily visible.

Comment: @Ben: It's easily fixed; have the default value of `Piecewise[]` be `Indeterminate` instead of `0`; thus, `Plot[{Piecewise[{{Sin[x], 0 <= x <= Pi/2}}, Indeterminate], Piecewise[{{Sin[x], Pi/2 <= x <= 2 Pi}}, Indeterminate]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Directive[Black, Dashed]}]`.

Comment: @J.M.: Thanks everybody. That solves this problem for me. And it was quite simple.

Answer (score 9):

Yet another alternative: Some combination of `Mesh` and `MeshShading`

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> Red,
 Ticks -> {{0, π/2, π, (3 π)/2, 2 Pi}, Automatic}, 
 Mesh -> {{π/2}}, 
 MeshStyle -> None, 
 MeshShading -> Directive/@{{Thick, Dashing[Tiny], Green}, {Dashed, Red}}]
```

[image]

To add legends:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
 Ticks -> {{0, π/2, π, (3 π)/2, 2 Pi}, Automatic}, 
 Mesh -> {{π/2}}, 
 MeshStyle -> None, 
 MeshShading -> Directive /@ {{Thick, Dashing[Tiny], Green}, {Dashed, Red}}, 
 Epilog ->  Inset[Panel@
 Grid[{{Graphics[{Thick, Green, Dashing[Tiny], 
    Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, AspectRatio -> .1, ImageSize -> 30],
    Style["x <= π/2 ", 12, 
    Green]}, {Graphics[{Dashed, Red, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, 
    AspectRatio -> .1, ImageSize -> 30], 
    Style["x >= π/2 ", 12, Red]}}], 
 Offset[{-10, -10}, Scaled[{1, 1}]], {Right, Top}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice use of mesh. +1

Answer (score 8):

```
ShowLegend[
 Show[
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, \[Pi]/2}, PlotStyle -> Dashing[None],
  Ticks -> {{0, \[Pi]/2, \[Pi], (3 \[Pi])/2, 2 Pi}, Automatic}], 
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, \[Pi]/2, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> Dashing[Tiny],
  Ticks -> {{0, \[Pi]/2, \[Pi], (3 \[Pi])/2, 2 Pi}, Automatic}], 
  PlotRange -> All
 ],
 {
  {Graphics[{ColorData[1][1], ##2, Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}}]}], #} &
    @@@ {{"Acute \[Angle]"}, {"Other \[Angle]", Dashed}}
 }
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I like this solution.  You can delete it again if you want to but I'll just post it as my own.

Comment: I deleted it because in re-reading the OP I realised that it didn't actually answer the question, as they had had exactly the same problem as I encountered. Namely that I didn't seem to be able to get `PlotLegend` to work with `Show`.

Comment: Please see my update.  If you feel it is still no good do as you will.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  Thanks, after your additions I think it fully answers the OP.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Thanks. I was also interested in how to also do this with Show.

Answer (score 3):

Very dirty trick to enable you to use the methods in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1128):

```
plt = Plot[Piecewise[{{Sqrt[Haversine[2 x]], 0 <= x <= Pi/2},
           {Sin[x], Pi/2 < x}}], {x, 0, 2 Pi}];
li = Cases[plt, _Line, Infinity];
Graphics[Transpose[{{Dashing[None], Dashing[Small]}, li}], 
 AspectRatio -> OptionValue[Plot, AspectRatio], Axes -> True]
```

As for the legend... you could do what b.gatessucks did, but I'm told there are better options. Search around the site for stuff on legends.

Comment: So what really makes this work? Mathematically, Haversine[2x] is equal to Sin[x] on the interval [0, Pi/2]. It looks like plt has the form {Line[], Line[] }. So the plot thinks of it as two different functions still. Is this right? Interesting solution.

Comment: @Ben, no; $\mathrm{hav}(x)=\sin^2\dfrac{x}{2}$. Otherwise, yes; I'm exploiting the fact that $\mathrm{hav}(x)$ is not immediately simplified to more basic trigonometric functions.

Comment: Oh yeah, I meant to take the square root above. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A more generalized version of [b.gatessucks' answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6827/1356):

```
xmin = 0; xmax = 2*Pi;
range = {xmin, Pi/2, xmax};
intervals[x_, range_] := LessEqual @@@ (Insert[#, x, 2] & /@ 
                           Delete[Thread[{range, RotateLeft@range}], -1])
fun[x_] := Sin@x
Plot[Evaluate@(Piecewise[{{fun[x], #}}, Indeterminate] & /@ intervals[x, range]), 
  {x, xmin, xmax}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Red, Dashed}, {Black, Dotted}}, 
  Ticks -> {Range[xmin, xmax, Pi/2], Automatic}]
```

[image]

Then, one can more easily do this kind of plot:

[image]