# How to plot data with different colors (or symbols) depending on a condition

Tags: plotting, conditional

Let's consider a simple example. I want to plot a function on `[0;2]`, depending on a condition: if `x<1`, I want to plot `x^2`, otherwise `x^2-1`. I found out how to do it:

```
 Plot[If[x < 1, x^2, x^2 - 1], {x, 0, 2}]
```

But in my problem I need to plot the same function (`x^2`), with 1 color for `x<1` and with another color otherwise (say, blue and red). I didn't find how to it. It seems like I cannot include colormap function inside the `if` condition.

Thanks

Comment: Make two plots and combine with Show.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. When I plot them separately (defining color using `PlotStyle`), everything works. Once I combine them with `Show` function, it plots everything with the second color, ignoring the first

Comment: That is simply not possible. `Show` never changes the colour.  Are you using `Show[Plot[..., PlotStyle -> Red],  Plot[..., PlotStyle -> Blue], PlotRange -> All]`?  I forgot to say that you might need `PlotRange -> All` within `Show`.

Comment: That works, thanks

Comment: You can convert your `If` expression to `Piecewise` with `PiecewiseExpand`, and then this question is a direct duplicate of the one now linked above your post.  See also: [(6826)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6826/121), [(8199)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8199/121)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of ways of doing this by combining 2 curves.  For example

```
Plot[{If[x < 1, x^2], If[x > 1, x^2 - 1]}, {x, 0, 2},  PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

I don't know if there is a way where the colour information can be tagged to the values themselves.

Answer (score 6):

One possibility :

```
 Plot[
     If[x < 1, x^2, x^2 - 1],
     {x, 0, 2},
     Mesh -> {{1.001}}, 
     MeshFunctions -> {#1 &},
     MeshShading -> {Blue, Red}
     ]
```

[image]