# How to use both solid and dashed line in a single curve

Tags: plotting, color, graphics

I want to edit this code from the wolfram Documentation Center so that, the red curve comes as dashed lines and the black comes in solid.
How to do that using ColorFunction?

Colour a curve red when its absolute coordinate is above 0:

```
Plot[
 Sinc[x], {x, 0, 10}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, If[y > 0, Red, Black]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

Comment: related/possible duplicate: [Plot that draws a dashed/solid curve depending on the y-value of the curve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73389/125) and  [How to plot a series using different colors depending on the y-value](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59951/125)?

Comment: also [How do you plot the same function with different options over different intervals?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6826/125)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 10}, MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y}, y]}, 
 Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshShading -> {Automatic, Directive[Dashed, Red]}, 
 PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't there any way to add colours? I tried this, but didn't get the desired result, Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 10}, MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y}, y]}, 
 Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshShading -> {Red, Dashed}, PlotStyle -> Thick]

Comment: @user84456 `Directive[Dashed, Red]`

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

SolveValues[{Sinc[x] == 0, 0 <= x <= 10}, x]

(* {π, 2 π, 3 π} *)

Plot[Evaluate[
  ConditionalExpression[Sinc[x], #] & /@
   {x < Pi || 2 Pi < x < 3 Pi, Pi < x < 2 Pi || x > 3 Pi}],
 {x, 0, 10},
 PlotStyle -> {{Red, Dashed, Thick}, {Black, Thick}}]
```

[image]