# Intersection of any triangle with a circle in Cartesian coordinates

Tags: plotting, geometry

I started  a notebook dealing with metrics in a triangle and its intersection points  by a circle. Up to now I reached the point  of having plotted a triangle, a circle with an arbitrary centre and I know the coordinates where they intersect.
Before going further with adding  more meaningful circles and more lines I would like to know if there is  a better way of finding the coordinates of the points where the triangle intersects the circle.
Here is my code:

```
eqc[c_, r_] := {(x - c[[1]])^2 + (y - c[[2]])^2 - 
r^2}  (*   c: {x,y} coord.centre  r: radius *) 
a = {2, 4}; b = {7, 1}; c = {-1, -4}; (* triangle vertices *)
c1 = eqc[{5/2, 4/7}, 3]; (* expression for plotting the circle *)

fctline[a_, b_] := 
Reduce[Det[{{x, y, 1},  (*  Finds equation of a line between 2 points a{x,y} b{x,y) *) 
            {a[[1]], a[[2]], 1},
            {b[[1]], b[[2]], 1}}] == 0, y];

lineA = fctline[c, b];  (* fct of line oposite vertex A *)
lineB = fctline[c, a];
lineC = fctline[a, b];

coordpts[c_, line_] := 
Module[{eqns},   (* module computing coords. 
intersection of a line with a circle *)
  eqns = {c == 0, y - line[[2]] == 0};
  {x, y} /. Solve[eqns, {x, y}]];
trpts = Flatten[{coordpts[c1, lineA], coordpts[c1, lineB], 
coordpts[c1, lineC]}, 1];

symbolsI = FromCharacterCode /@ (Range[Length@trpts] + 944);
symbolsV = {A, B, C};

plotA = Plot[{Transpose[(y /. Solve[# == 0, y]) & /@ c1]}, {x, -5, 
15},  (* triangle to be added next step *)
PlotStyle -> {Black, Black, Black, Blue},
PlotRange -> {{-3, 8}, {-6, 6}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0.5, 
AspectRatio -> Automatic,
Epilog -> {
{Red, PointSize[0.01], Point[trpts],
 (Text[Style[#, 15], #2 + {-0.2, .2}] & @@@ 
   Transpose[{symbolsI, trpts}])},
{Black, PointSize[0.001], Point[{a, b, c}],
 (Text[Style[#, 20], #2 + {-0.3, .3}] & @@@ 
   Transpose[{symbolsV, {a, b, c}}])}}]
```

To plot the sides of the triangle with lines strictly limited to the sides of the triangle I anticipated a rather repetitive process (i.e. plot nine segments of lines, six of them with a `Transparent` graphics attributes) but I found in [Proper way to Plot a single function in two different styles?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8199) a nice solution to deal with that with less code.

```
SetAttributes[splitplot, HoldAll];  (* thanks to Simon Woods *)
splitplot[pieces__] := Piecewise[{#}, I] & /@ Unevaluated@pieces
splitplot[{v_, c_}] := splitplot[{v, c}, {v, ! c}]
splitstyle[styles__] := 
Module[{st = 
Directive /@ {styles}}, {{Last[st = RotateLeft@st], #}} &]

sideA = Plot[{splitplot[{lineA[[2]], 
  x < -1 || x > 7}, {lineA[[2]], -1 <= x <= 7}]} ,
  {x, -2, 8}, 
PlotStyle -> 
splitstyle[{Transparent, Black}, {Transparent, Black}, {Black}]];
sideB = Plot[{splitplot[{lineB[[2]], 
  x < -1 || x > 2}, {lineB[[2]], -1 <= x <= 2}]} ,
  {x, -2, 8}, 
PlotStyle -> 
splitstyle[{Transparent, Black}, {Transparent, Black}, {Black}]];
sideC = Plot[{splitplot[{lineC[[2]], x < 2 || x > 7}, {lineC[[2]], 
  2 <= x <= 7}]} ,
  {x, -2, 8}, 
PlotStyle -> 
splitstyle[{Transparent, Black}, {Transparent, Black}, {Black}]];

Show[plotA, sideA, sideB, sideC, Axes -> None, ImageSize -> 600]
```

As you can see I considered the triangle as a set of three lines. That's certainly not elegant but a triangle is not a locust of points than  can be determined  by a general function as for any conics, function that you can integrate or differentiate. There is perhaps a function for it in higher mathematics  and if so  may be a built-in (undocumented) in MMA is available.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, what is the question? If how to draw a triangle, then you need nothing more than `EdgeForm@Thick, FaceForm@None, Polygon[{a, b, c}]` in `Epilog`.

Comment: The question is about getting the cartesian coordinates of the points where a circle intersects a triangle - with less code as here where I had to plot three lines and solve three equations, where each line intersects the circle.

Comment: Ok, so the data is: 3 points for traingle, center and radius for circle, right? Also, is precission important?

Comment: Yes, I start with 3 points for the triangle , 1 point for the centre of the circle, length of its radius. I could not find a way to write a single `Solve` between the equation of the circle and an analytic expression representing  the triangle.  Precision of the intersection points coordinates is very important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`RegionIntersection`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionIntersection). Your example:

```
triangle = Line[{{2, 4}, {7, 1}, {-1, -4}, {2, 4}}];
circle = Circle[{5/2, 4/7}, 3];

pts = RegionIntersection[triangle, circle]
```

> Point[{{1/476 (1847 - 15 Sqrt[1335]), 
>      1/476 (1367 + 9 Sqrt[1335])}, {1/476 (1847 + 15 Sqrt[1335]), 
>      1/476 (1367 - 9 Sqrt[1335])}, {1/623 (2225 + 12 Sqrt[9523]), (-1424 + 
>       15 Sqrt[9523])/
>      1246}, {1/623 (2225 - 12 Sqrt[9523]), (-1424 - 15 Sqrt[9523])/1246}}]

Visualization:

```
Graphics[{triangle, circle, Red, PointSize[Large], pts}]
```

[image]

Comment: Pleasant surprise! A first answer nearly four years since my question was posted!