# Plot the minimum of a list of functions

Tags: plotting, functions

This is my first question on any stack-exchange site and I'm also very new to using *Mathematica* software so please excuse/correct me if I mess up.

I would like to take a list of functions of a single variable {$f_1, f_2, f_3, \ldots, f_n$}, and plot the minimum value that each of these functions takes on at any point over an interval $[x_0, x_f]$.

So far this much is not so difficult (or has not been the difficult part for me to figure out).
However, I would like for each of the intervals over which any function $f_i$ is the minimum to correspond to it's own color (like how Plot usually attributes different colors to different curves when you plot multiple functions) and further I'd like to include a legend that clearly denotes which function from the list corresponds to which color.

I can do the first part fairly easily using the following:

```
Z[x_] = Min[x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5]
Plot[Z[x], {x, 0, 2}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image: Plotting the minimum value of a list of multiple functions]

I would like something that would color the segment of the curve where $x^5$ is the minimum function in the list one color and the segment where $x$ is the minimum function in another color and denote the color representations on the legend on the right.

I can plot each of the functions separately with the color-coding system like so:

```
Plot[{x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5}, {x, 0, 2}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image: Plotting multiple functions with color-coding and legend]

And in both cases the " PlotLegends -> "Expressions" " flag/option (not sure what the terminology is for *Mathematica* functions) does nicely generate a legend as I'd like it.

But I don't really have a sense of how to combine the two.

Thanks in advance for the help, and while I didn't find any other questions that might help answer (or partially answer) this question please correct me if I missed any.

Comment: An idea for a solution I would want to use but don't know how to implement is generating a list of {g1, g2, ..., gn} defined so that g_i = f_i when f_i is the minimum of all the functions and is undefined otherwise. Then plotting all these functions would be (I suspect) sufficient by the means as the second attempt above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### New method

Inspired by your self-answer we can automate things as follows:

```
prep[fn_][a__] := If[# == fn[a], #] & /@ {a}
```

Now:

```
Plot[prep[Min][x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5], {x, 0, 2},
 BaseStyle -> {14, Thick},
 Frame -> True,
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue},
 Evaluated -> True
]
```

[image]

Although untested I presume this will work with `PlotLegends`.  Note:

- `prep` is somewhat generalized so that it can work with other functions
- `Evaluated -> True` is used rather than `Evaluate` to keep `x` localized to the `Plot`
- This method doesn't work in version 9.0.0 due to a bug. [(47981)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47981/121)

---

### Old methods

It may surprise you to learn that *Mathematica* internally splits the [`Line`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Line.html) on discontinuities (when using the default value `Automatic` for the [`Exclusions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Exclusions.html) option), which allows you do use the post-processing method shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1129/121) (bottom), e.g.:

```
f[x_] := Min[x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5]

Module[{i = 1},
 Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
  /. x_Line :> {ColorData[1][i++], x}
]
```

[image]

Or Simon Woods's [`splitstyle`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8225/121):

```
splitstyle[styles__] := 
  Module[{st = Directive /@ {styles}}, {{Last[st = RotateLeft @ st], #}} &];

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> splitstyle[Red, Green], BaseStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

#### Notes

I don't have the `PlotLegends` option in version 7, which I use, therefore I cannot test that aspect of the question.  Pardon me for not mentioning that directly.

You asked for an explanation of these methods.  They are similar, yet work different.  Both rely on the operation of the [`Exclusions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Exclusions.html) mechanism of `Plot`.  When a discontinuity is found a new [`Line`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Line.html) primitive is created within the [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Graphics.html) expression that is produced by Plot.  The first method works by replacing (see [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html)) each `Line` expression with a `{style, Line}` pair.  (`style` is drawn from an arbitrarily selected [`ColorData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorData.html) scheme.)

The second method relies on a clever construction and the behavior of the `PlotStyle` option when it is given a function as its value.  The function *generated* by `splitstyle` uses [this method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3876/121) to cycle between given styles (not used in this example, but useful elsewhere).  It also produces a `{style, Line[ . . . ]}` pair, and this expression is inserted by `Plot` itself rather than with post-processing.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response.

This doesn't seem to address the generation of a legend request here, however. Will the PlotLegends option used in my question still work to handle this?
Further, being new to mathematica the syntax or methods used here are a little lost on me. I'll read up on this but further explanation of how this works would be awesome and whether I should have a reason to choose one method over the other would be appreciated as well.

Comment: @Moodragonx You're welcome.

Comment: @Moodragonx More notes added.  Sorry I can't help with the `PlotLegends` option, at least not directly.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Just thought I'd confirm that PlotLegends -> "Expressions" doesn't provide a separate legend entry for each section of the curve (which I expected since it is still only a single function f[x] being plotted).

Comment: @Moodragonx Unsurprising, really.  Let me think about how to approach that problem, at least with the tools I have.

Comment: Hmm, your "new method" just gives me a blank plot. (Mathematica 9 on Mac OS X.)

Comment: @Rahul Well bollocks.  Does `Piecewise` work for you?  I can update my answer to use that instead, though it's a little more verbose.

Comment: On my machine `Plot` seems to give up as soon as any of the functions are `Undefined` everywhere. So I don't think `Piecewise` would help. That's why I had to use `RegionFunction` in my answer.

Comment: @Rahul Please try my "New method" with this:  `prep[fn_][a__] := Piecewise[{{#, # == fn[a]}}, Indeterminate] & /@ {a}`

Comment: No, that doesn't help either.

Comment: Removing the "Indeterminate" parameter in Piecewise (and thus letting the default value of the function settle at 0 where you can not see it over the axes bars) seems to fix the error on my end. Also adding PlotRange -> All seems necessary.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, i.e. Your middle definition of prep[fn_][a__] := Piecewise[{{#, # == fn[a]}}] & /@ {a}, seems to work for me (when specifying the PlotRange).

Comment: @Moodragonx Apparently the changed how both `If` and `Indeterminate` behave.  I guess you are supposed to use `ConditionalExpression` now.  I'll stick that in my answer too.

Comment: @Moodragonx Would you please see if the new "for version 8" code works as expected?  I wish they hadn't changed things...

Comment: @Rahul You too, please, if you have time.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Hmm... neither version of prep currently work for me (I am on Mathematica 9.0 if that is elucidating), but the form I cited before does.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I see the same behaviour as Moodragonx's last two comments, presumably because we're on the same version of Mathematica. However, instead of the curves stopping they drop to zero: http://i.stack.imgur.com/J5AIb.png

Comment: @RahulNarain Ah, yes I removed the BaseStyle -> {14, Thick}, to conceal the fact that the other functions are still being plotted at 0. Perhaps not the best solution since there are times when the x-axis won't align with y=0, and just that it seems inelligent. But using Indeterminate seems to force no other functions to be plotted on those intervals.

Comment: Interesting news: Both definitions work fine on Mathematica 9.0.1.0 on Linux. My previous comments were on Mathematica 9.0.0.0 on Mac.

Comment: @Rahul A little late but interesting nevertheless.  Please post any further observations [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47981/121).  Thanks. :-)

Comment: @Moodragonx Apparently the problem is a bug in version 9.0.0.  Can you confirm that is what you are using?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I am currently away from a machine with Mathematica on it and will not have access until the next semester begins in the fall. In the meantime I'm not really sure what to pick as a "best answer" as I've not yet seen if your method works with a legend for a non-buggy version of Mathematica.

Comment: @Moodragonx You can wait to Accept an answer if you like.  Also, should it *not* work with the built-in legend system you can still build a legend from `Graphics` primitives as Jens did [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4028/121).  Anyway, I hope to see you back here this autumn.

Answer (score 7):

Simple solution using `RegionFunction`:

```
f[x_] := {x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5};
Plot[Evaluate@f[x], {x, 0, 2}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, y == Min[f[x]]], PlotPoints -> 20, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> ColorData[35, "ColorList"]]
```

[image]

One limitation is that you get overshooting unless you fiddle with the number of `PlotPoints`.

The only reason I changed the `PlotStyle` is because the first and fifth colours are hard to tell apart in the default colour scheme.

Comment: Great idea!  I suggest using `Evaluated -> True` here to localize `x`, assuming that doesn't break anything.

Comment: I'm a little wary of using [undocumented](http://reference.wolfram.com/documentation-search.html?query=Evaluated&collection=reference&lang=en) options...

Comment: Awesome. This seems to do exactly what I want. I feel silly for not knowing how RegionFunction worked but that's essentially exactly what I was looking for.
Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```
flist = Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 4}];
pieces = Table[ConditionalExpression[f, f == Min[flist]], {f, flist}]; (* thanks Rahul *)
pltstyls = Join[#, Directive[{#, Thickness[.01], Dashed}] & /@ #] &[
            ColorData[1, "ColorList"][[;; Length@flist]]];
lgndlbls = Join[#, StringJoin["piece ", #] &/@ (ToString /@ #)]&[TraditionalForm /@ flist];


Plot[Evaluate@Join[flist, pieces], {x, 0, 10},
     Filling -> Thread[Range[Length@flist] -> Axis], ImageSize -> 500,
     PlotStyle -> pltstyls, PlotLegends -> lgndlbls]
```

[image]

**Update:** Generalizing to arbitrary list of functions `flist` and functionals on `flist`:

```
 foo = Module[{pieces =Table[ConditionalExpression[f, f == #[#2]], {f, #2}], 
        styles = Join[#, Directive[{#, Thickness[.01], Dashed}] & /@ #] &[
                    #3[[;; Length@#2]]],
       lgndlbls =  Join[#, StringJoin["piece ", #] & /@ (ToString /@ #)] &[
                    TraditionalForm /@ #2]},
 Plot[Evaluate@Join[#2, pieces], {x, 0, 10}, 
        Filling -> Thread[Range[Length@#2] -> Axis], ImageSize -> 500, 
        PlotStyle -> styles, PlotLegends -> lgndlbls]] &;

 foo[RankedMin[#, 2] &, flist, ColorData[1, "ColorList"]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is an interesting solution. If you get the chance, some explanation of what's at work here would be nice. I've also been having some trouble generalizing this to other functions I might use (different lists with different numbers of functions) some help using this solution would be appreciated :).

Comment: Suggestion: define `pieces` simply as `Table[ConditionalExpression[f, f == Min[flist]], {f, flist}]` :) Also note that this approach suffers from the same problems that plague Mr.Wizard's "New Method" on Mathematica 9.

Comment: @RahulNarain, thank you. Updated with your suggestion. Re the version/OS related issues, this seems to work ok on MMA version 9.0.1 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 5):

I have somewhat devised a solution that does what I'm looking for but requires manually generating a list of functions that I'd like to avoid.

```
Z[x_] = Min[x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5]
g1[x_] = Piecewise[{{x, x == Z[x]}}]
g2[x_] = Piecewise[{{x^2, x^2 == Z[x]}}]
g3[x_] = Piecewise[{{x^3, x^3 == Z[x]}}]
g4[x_] = Piecewise[{{x^4, x^4 == Z[x]}}]
g5[x_] = Piecewise[{{x^5, x^5 == Z[x]}}]
Plot[{g1[x], g2[x], g3[x], g4[x], g5[x]}, {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

Produces the following output

[image: Somewhat Desired Result]

Some way to automate this would be much more preferred. In general I might want to err on the side of using Mr.Wizard's solution for my use case as I intend to do this repeated for lists of many functions at a time.

Further it might be nice for the expressions in the legend to include the original definitions of the functions $f$, but this is something that can be adjust manually fairly easily.

Comment: Does the problem you just reported also affect my "New method" on your system?  You can try adding the option `PlotRange -> All` to yours to see if that corrects it.

Comment: Okay I submit to having completely novice knowledge of how to plot in _Mathematica_. PlotRange -> All does in fact fix my "error".

Comment: Please review the present version of my answer. I included three different definitions for `prep`; could you try each of them and report which, if any, work for you?