# What is the syntax to conditionally suppress plotting in version 9?

Tags: plotting, bugs, conditional

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and fixed in 9.0.1**

---

In *Mathematica* 7 it is very easy to conditionally suppress plotting of individual lines using `If`:

```
Plot[{
  If[x^2 < 2, x^2],
  If[Exp[x] > x^2, Exp[x]],
  If[False, x]                (* check recommended by Rahul *)
 },
 {x, -2, 2},
 PlotStyle -> Thick, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Or more verbosely using `Piecewise` and `Indeterminate`:

```
Plot[{
  Piecewise[{{x^2, x^2 < 2}}, Indeterminate],
  Piecewise[{{Exp[x], Exp[x] > x^2}}, Indeterminate],
  Piecewise[{{x, False}}, Indeterminate]      (* check recommended by Rahul *)
  },
 {x, -2, 2},
 PlotStyle -> Thick, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

It is reported that neither method works in **version 9.0.0** (at least on OSX.)
Furthermore it is reported that my attempt using [`ConditionalExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ConditionalExpression.html) also fails:

```
Plot[{
  ConditionalExpression[x^2, x^2 < 2],
  ConditionalExpression[Exp[x], Exp[x] > x^2]
  },
 {x, -2, 2},
 PlotStyle -> Thick, Frame -> True]
```

Plotting a zero is reported to "work" but that is hardly a solution:

```
Plot[{
  Piecewise[{{x^2, x^2 < 2}}],
  Piecewise[{{Exp[x], Exp[x] > x^2}}]
  },
 {x, -2, 2},
 PlotStyle -> Thick, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

**1. Is this indeed a bug in version 9.0.0?**

**2. Is there a workaround for the affected systems?**

Comment: [It seems to work unless I missed something.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6dled44grb96ves/Screenshot%202014-05-16%2013.33.18.png)

Comment: @Szabolcs Which version are you using?  A [recent comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47967/plot-the-minimum-of-a-list-of-functions?lq=1#comment143349_47968) indicates this may be a bug in version `9.0.0`.

Comment: @Szabolcs I agree - it works for me on OSX and version 9.0.1.

Comment: @Jens Thanks; it seems it is a bug of limited scope.  Could someone with v9.0.0 NOT on OSX give this a try?

Comment: Too bad, I would have loved the opportunity to bash version 9, since I still prefer version 8 for most things in real life...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm using 9.0.1 (from the version string it's not very clear but 9.0.0 was released in November, and 9.0.1 in January).  9.0.0 had *lots* of bugs and I think no one should be using it ... there are many examples of bugs fixed in 9.0.1 on this site.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for your help.

Comment: I do wonder if WRI gives free point updates for non-premiere-service users (I don't know)

Comment: What I remember -- I'm no longer at home with my Mac laptop to try these out -- is that the problem only appears if there is a function which is `Undefined` *everywhere* on the plot, so no line can be drawn for it at all. @Szabolcs, can you try it again plotting, say, `{If[x^2 < 2, x^2], If[False, x]}`?

Comment: @Rahul Interesting; I shall include that.

Comment: @RahulNarain You are correct - I just checked on a different computer with version 9.0.0, and with your line included it produces a blank plot. But without that line, the plot seems to work fine even on that version.

Comment: @Rahul [It still seems to work fine.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b6mr65147pu3i56/Screenshot%202014-05-16%2013.52.55.png)

Comment: Going by Jens's and Szabolcs's comments it does seem like a bug that was fixed in 9.0.1 then. I didn't know 9.0.0 was so well known to be bug-ridden.

Comment: @Rahul Almost everything tagged with [tag:version-9.0.0] is about bugs introduced in 9.0.0 and fixed in 9.0.1 and you'll find additional examples (both bugs and annoyances) in the chatlogs.

Comment: V.9.0.0 was so buggy that WRI offered a free upgrade to V9.0.1 to all V.9.0.0 license holders, not just to Premier Service subscribers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this bug seems to be tied directly to the appearance of `Indeterminate` as the only available function value in the plot range, it could perhaps be considered a work-around to replace `Indeterminate` by another "quantity" that behaves the same way as `Indeterminate` but doesn't cause the whole display of all other functions to be suppressed.

I tried the following, and it works on version 9.0.0:

```
Plot[{Piecewise[{{x^2,x^2<2}},Indeterminate],
  Piecewise[{{Exp[x],Exp[x]>x^2}},Indeterminate],
  Piecewise[{{x,False}},I]      (*modified check recommended by Rahul*)},
 {x,-2,2},
 PlotStyle->Thick,Frame->True]
```

Here, I used the imaginary unit `I` to produce the same effect as `Indeterminate`, and the remaining plots do still get displayed.

To make this more general, maybe one can use a replacement rule like this:

```
Plot[Evaluate[{Piecewise[{{x^2, x^2 < 2}}, Indeterminate], 
    Piecewise[{{Exp[x], Exp[x] > x^2}}, Indeterminate], 
    Piecewise[{{x, False}}, 
     Indeterminate]      (*modified check recommended by Rahul*)} /. 
   Indeterminate -> I], {x, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> Thick, Frame -> True]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my Version 9.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (November 20, 2012) Release ID 9.0.0.0 (3868239, 384640), Patch level 0,

```
Plot[{ConditionalExpression[x^2,x^2<2],ConditionalExpression[Exp[x],Exp[x]>x^2]},{x,-2,2},PlotStyle->Thick,Frame->True]
```

works normally, but neither

```
Plot[{If[x^2<2,x^2],If[Exp[x]>x^2,Exp[x]],If[False,x]                (*check recommended by Rahul*)},{x,-2,2},PlotStyle->Thick,Frame->True]
```

nor

```
Plot[{Piecewise[{{x^2,x^2<2}},Indeterminate],Piecewise[{{Exp[x],Exp[x]>x^2}},Indeterminate],Piecewise[{{x,False}},Indeterminate]      (*check recommended by Rahul*)},{x,-2,2},PlotStyle->Thick,Frame->True]
```

do : only a frame for x=-2 to +2 and y from -1 to +1 get plotted (with x=0 and y=0 line).
Does that make sense?