# Plotting two functions in one graph, with different value ranges

Tags: plotting

```
Plot[2x, {x,0,4}];
Plot[x^2, {x,4,8}];
```

How do I merge these two graphs into one?

Comment: `Show[
 Plot[2 x, {x, 0, 4}],
 Plot[x^2, {x, 4, 8}], PlotRange -> All]`?

Comment: Related topics: [(128)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128/121),
[(627)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/627/121),
[(1128)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1128/121),
[(8199)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8199/121),
[(77397)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77397/121)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way that may serve you also for other purposes:

```
p[x_, left_, right_] := HeavisideTheta[x - left] HeavisideTheta[right - x]
Plot[{2 x p[x, 0, 4], x^2 p[x, 4, 8]}, {x, 0, 8}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another example:

```
tab = Table[x^(1/n) p[x, n, n + 1], {n, 1, 10}]; 
Plot[tab, {x, 0, 8}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

Update: Using thicker lines to make the difference between various methods `visible`:

```
Plot[{ConditionalExpression[2 x, 0 <= x < 4], ConditionalExpression[x^2, 4 < x <= 8]}, {x, 0, 8}, 
 BaseStyle -> Thickness[.02]]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{Piecewise[{{2 x, 0<=x<4}}, Indeterminate], 
      Piecewise[{{x^2, 4<x<= 8}}, Indeterminate]}, {x, 0, 8}, BaseStyle -> Thickness[.02]]
```

[image]

```
ct = ConditionalExpression[#, #2] & @@@ Table[{x^(1/n), n < x <= n + 1}, {n, 10}];
Plot[ct, {x, 0, 8}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[.02]]
```

[image]

```
pw = Piecewise[{{#, #2}}, Indeterminate] & @@@ Table[{x^(1/n), n < x <= n + 1}, {n, 10}];
Plot[pw, {x, 0, 8}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[.02]]
```

[image]

whereas,

```
p[x_, left_, right_] := HeavisideTheta[x - left] HeavisideTheta[right - x]
Plot[{2 x p[x, 0, 4], x^2 p[x, 4, 8]}, {x, 0, 8}, BaseStyle -> Thickness[.02]]
```

[image]

```
tab = Table[x^(1/n) p[x, n, n + 1], {n, 1, 10}];
Plot[tab, {x, 0, 8}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[.02]]
```

[image]

Similarly, using `Boole` in place of `HeavisideTheta`:

```
Plot[{2 x Boole[0 <= x <= 4], x^2 Boole[4 < x <= 8]}, {x, 0, 8}, BaseStyle -> Thickness[.02]]
```

[image]

Comment: If single-color plot is acceptable, `Piecewise` approach can be simplified to `Plot[Piecewise[{{2 x, 0 <= x < 4}, {x^2, 4 < x <= 8}}, Indeterminate], {x, 0, 8}]`

Comment: @Bob, multiple colors is in fact the reason for the clunkier multiple `Piecewise`s.