# Does not Show as combined plot

Tags: plotting

```
F[u_, v_] = {(1 + u v)/(u + v), (u - v)/(u + v), (1 - u v)/(u + v)};
gr1 = ParametricPlot3D[F[u, v], {u, 0, 2.}, {v, 0, 2.}]
gr2 = ParametricPlot3D[F[u - v, u + v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}]
Show[{gr1, gr2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Suspect that it may be due to calculation of infinite range.

Comment: You're sort of right. `gr2` has a vastly greater `PlotRange` than `gr1`. The surface that mathematica gives for `gr1` lies within about 3 units from the origin. The surface for `gr2` has an extent of about `10^7`. `gr1` is but a speck on `gr2`. To see this pass the `Axes->True` option to all three plots.

Comment: Oh, also the surfaces of gr1 and gr2 match exactly (no surprise there, as you are basically using the same function to draw both of them). try defining `gr1` with the option `PlotStyle->Red` for example, then use `Show[{gr1,gr2}]` without the option `PlotRange->All` and you'll see the red and blue surfaces on top of each other.

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = {#, PlotRange@#2} & @@@
   {{"gr1", gr1}, {"gr2", gr2},
    {"Show[gr1,gr2]", Show[gr1, gr2]},
    {"Show[gr1,gr2, PlotRange -> All]",Show[gr1, gr2, PlotRange -> All]}};
Grid[lst, Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

whereas the ranges that cover the plot ranges of `gr1` and `gr2`:

```
Transpose[Through@{Min @@@ # &, Max @@@ # &}@Thread[PlotRange /@ {gr1, gr2}]]
(* {{0., 3.78083}, {-6.98504, 1.}, {-0.75, 8.47028}} *)
```

A work-around is to use an explicit setting for `PlotRange` computed from the plot ranges of `gr1` and `gr2`.

```
Show[gr1, gr2, ImageSize -> 400,
 PlotRange -> Transpose[Through@{Min@@@#&, Max@@@#&}@ Thread[PlotRange /@ {gr1, gr2}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Your code is not generating the same outputs on my machine. `gr2` consistently gives those crazy `10^7` ranges, which suggests to me, that everything _is_ working as intended.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP, may well be version/os dependent (I am using version 9.0.1.0 windows 8 x64).

Comment: Sorry for misleading, a restart of the kernel made my output the same as yours. I'd note that your custom `PlotRange` specification is not (and should not be) the same as `PlotRange->All`. It gives the union of the ranges of `gr1` and `gr2`, while setting it to `All` extends the plot to include the entire parametric surface which is not entirely shown in `gr2` by default.

Comment: We cannot tailor the Ranges manually ourselves ( as user) . There should be specific statement from Documentation when  PlotRange-> All is useful and when it is not useful.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP, good point. I also agree with you that `PlotRange->All` is working as advertised.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you cannot include plot parameters into Show, so try:

```
Show[gr1, gr2]
```

Comment: You absolutely can include plot parameters in show, it's an extremely useful feature.

Comment: Was this always possible? Because I often have problems with this, and include it in one of the plots I want to show. Also, in the problem stated here, it seems to work in the way I suggested. So it is unclear to me why what the problem is.

Comment: I don't know the history of the development of `Show`, but the code in OP also throws no error. By default, `Show` uses the parameters of the first graphics object passed to it, but these parameters can be overridden by options passed to `Show` itself. Therefore if you use just `Show[gr1,gr2]` you get the plot with the `PlotRange` of `gr1`, which, as I commented to the question, is much smaller, than the range of `gr2`, so you see both surfaces. When OP uses `PlotRange->All`, it expands to include `gr2` which is vastly bigger.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification, I'll check this out.

Comment: Plot parameters must be carried forward to Show, else the Show has no charm..I mean a full utility.I use ver 8. Neither gr1 nor gr2 has big Range but there is something hidden in PlotRange->All that includes widest Range.