# Adding legends when using Show

Tags: plotting, legending

I want to show my students that $f(x)=2\sin x-3$ and $f^{-1}(x)=\sin^{-1}\dfrac{x+3}{2}$ are inverses of one another via visual evidence; that is, $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are reflections of one another across the line $y=x$. Thus far, I have:

```
Show[
 Plot[2 Sin[x] - 3, {x, -π/2, π/2},
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}],
 Plot[ArcSin[(x + 3)/2], {x, -5, -1}],
 Plot[x, {x, -5, 5}],
 PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}},
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"},
 AspectRatio -> Automatic
 ]
```

Which gives this image:

[image]

Note that I've restricted $f$ and $f^-1$ to their domains. I'm wondering how I can add plot legends for each curve in this situation.

Answer (score 12):

I would add `PlotLabels` to each plot separately:

```
Show[Plot[2 Sin[x] - 3, {x, -π/2, π/2}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  PlotLabels -> "sin"], 
 Plot[ArcSin[(x + 3)/2], {x, -5, -1}, PlotLabels -> "arcsin"], 
 Plot[x, {x, -5, 5}, PlotLabels -> "x"], 
 PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Or making the plot colorful first:

```
plot = Show[
  Plot[2 Sin[x] - 3, {x, -π/2, π/2}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red], 
  Plot[ArcSin[(x + 3)/2], {x, -5, -1}, PlotStyle -> Green], 
  Plot[x, {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Blue], 
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

and then using `ShowLegend`:

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]
ShowLegend[plot, {{{Graphics[{Red, Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}}]}], 
    "sin"}, {Graphics[{Green, Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}}]}], 
    "arcsin"}, {Graphics[{Blue, Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}}]}], "x"}}, 
  LegendPosition -> {0.7, 0.2}, LegendSize -> {0.45, 0.4}, 
  LegendShadow -> False}]
```

[image]

Or, to incorporate [rcollyer's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127201/adding-legends-when-using-show/127213#comment344247_127213) below:

```
Legended[plot, LineLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"sin", "arcsin", "x"}]]
```

[image]

Comment: `ShowLegends` is deprecated as of v9. If you're using `PlotLabels`, then you have v11. So, I'd use `Legended[plot, LineLegend[{Red, Green, Blue}, {"sin", "arcsin", "x"}]]`.

Comment: @rcollyer I think that qualifies as an answer. // I was thinking how to _show_ a _legend_, so `ShowLegend` naturally came in mind. // Btw, I'm on v10.4

Comment: huh. The versions just sort of blur together after a while.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this ([like here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/64152)):

```
funcList[x_] = {2 Sin[x] - 3, ArcSin[(x + 3)/2], x};
funcRange = {{-π/2, π/2}, {-5, -1}, {-5, 5}};

Plot[Evaluate@MapThread[ConditionalExpression[#1, First@#2 <= x <Last@#2] &
, {funcList[x],funcRange}], {x, -5, 5}, PlotLegends -> funcList[x]
, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!