# Using mesh for a single function inside Plot

Tags: plotting

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, Mesh -> {{0, π}}, MeshShading -> {Black, Red}]
```

In the above, how can I specify that I want the mesh for just, say the `Sin` function and not the `Cos`? I know I can use two plots and combine them with `Show`, but this is not what I want.

Comment: `Show[
 {Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Mesh -> {{0, \[Pi]}}, 
   MeshShading -> {Black, Red}], 
  Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}, Mesh -> {{0, \[Pi]}}]}]`

Comment: @belisarius Isn't this what the OP explicitly says he doesn't want, or am I misreading this?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Yup. But my preferred shoe shop doesn't sell pairs of two right shoes unless you can convince them -with good reasons-

Comment: Since your own answer has nothing to do with `Mesh` shall we assume that you just want output that visually matches the graphic shown in that answer?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1128/121

Comment: Yes, that's true, I just wanted to get the visuals of the answer in a single plot command.

Answer (score 1):

```
Plot[{ConditionalExpression[Sin[x], 0 <= x <= Pi], 
      ConditionalExpression[Sin[x], Pi < x <= 10], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, 
      PlotStyle -> {Red, Black, Black}]
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't use `Mesh` at all, in contrast to what the question title states.

Comment: It is a good answer if the real question is how to generate that plot...

Answer (score 0):

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Boole[#2 === Sin[#1]] # &},
 Mesh -> {{0, Pi, 2 Pi, 3 Pi, 4 Pi}}, 
 MeshShading -> {Black, Directive[ Red, Thick]},
 PlotPoints -> 900]
```

[image]