# Plotting piecewise functions

Tags: plotting, piecewise, iterators

I have a list of `N` functions called `functionList`. `N` can be any number. Also, I have a list called `nodes` whose elements are in the interval `i` want to plot in.

My aim is to visualise in one graphic all the functions `functionList[[1]], functionList[[2]], ..., functionList[[n]]` in the respective subinterval.

This means to iterate over `functionList` and plot `functionList[[i]]` in the interval from `nodes[[i]] to nodes[[i+1]]`.

First, `functionList[[1]]` in the interval from `nodes[[1]] to nodes[[2]]`.
Then, `functionList[[2]]` in the interval from `nodes[[2]] to nodes[[3]]`.

I know about about
`Plot[Piecewise[{{x^2, x < 0}, {x, x > 0}}], {x, -2, 2}]`
but how can I combine with iterating over my `functionList`?

I am looking for something like this

```
Plot[Piecewise[{{functionList[[i]], x > nodes[[i]]&&x<nodes[[i+1]]}, {i,1,N}], {x, 0, 2}]
```

Comment: how about `funs = {x, x^2}``conds = {{x < 1}, {x >= 1}}``
f[x_] = Piecewise@Transpose[{funs, conds}] /. List[a_] -> a`

Comment: or `Piecewise@MapThread[{#1, Sequence @@ #2} &, {funs, conds}]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Sjoerd's example:

```
functionList = {Sin[x], x^2, Exp[x], x^3};
nodes = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};

Plot[Evaluate@MapThread[ConditionalExpression,  
                       {functionList,Thread[Most @ nodes < x <= Rest @ nodes]}],{x,0,4}]
```

or

```
Plot[Evaluate@Thread[ConditionalExpression@@ 
                       {functionList,Thread[Most @ nodes < x <= Rest @ nodes]}],{x,0,4}]
```

or

```
Plot[Evaluate@MapThread[Piecewise[{{##}},Indeterminate]&,
                {functionList,Thread[Most @ nodes < x <= Rest @ nodes]}],{x,0,4}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
functionList = {Sin[x], x^2, Exp[x], x^3};
nodes = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};

f[x_] = Piecewise[Transpose[{functionList, #1 <= x <= #2 & @@@ Partition[nodes, 2, 1]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: What's the easiest way, in the context of this solution, to have *Mathematica* automatically color the various pieces different colors -- much as would happen with a simple `Plot[{f1x, f2x, ..., fnx}, {x, a, b}]` expression -- *without* providing an explicit list of colors in a `PlotStyle` option?

Comment: @murray I don't think there's a really easy solution to that. You could split the Piecewise in several different ones or so, but I wouldn't call that easy. BTW Your approach (a list of colors in PlotStyle) wouldn't work as there's only one function (the Piecewise one) to work with.

Comment: @murray The closest I may get would be something like `f[x_] := functionList (Piecewise[{{1, #1 <= x <= #2}, {I, True}}] & @@@ Partition[nodes, 2, 1])` and then `Plot[f[x] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 4}]`. `Evaluate` is necessary for plot to realize there is more than one function involved.

Comment: I should have searched before asking; this was already asked and answered at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1128/plotting-piecewise-function-with-distinct-colors-in-each-section.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way that allows you to specify the colors of each interval.

```
colors={Red, Blue, Green, Orange};

Show[Thread[
   p[functionList, Partition[nodes, 2, 1] /. {a_, b_} :> {x, a, b}, 
    Thread[PlotStyle -> colors]]] /. p -> Plot, 
 PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

[image: pic]

---

Answer (score 1):

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 4}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x}, 
   Which[x < nodes[[1]], Red, nodes[[1]] < x < nodes[[2]], Green,
    nodes[[2]] < x < nodes[[3]], Orange, nodes[[3]] < x < nodes[[4]], 
    Yellow, nodes[[4]] < x, Purple]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Or... more generally:

```
PrependTo[nodes, -\[Infinity]];
AppendTo[nodes, \[Infinity]];

myColorList = Table[Hue[i/Length[nodes]], {i, Length[nodes]}];

Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 4}, 
  ColorFunction -> 
   Function[{x}, 
    Which @@ 
     Flatten@Table[{nodes[[i]] < x < nodes[[i + 1]], 
        myColorList[[i]]}, {i, Length[nodes] - 1}]
    ],
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```