# PlotStyle according to PlotRange

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have the function

```
Hypocycloid[{R_, r_}, θ_] := {(R - r) Cos[θ] + 
       r Cos[θ (R - r)/r], (R - r) Sin[θ] - 
       r Sin[θ (R - r)/r]}
```

For, e.g., R=5 and r=1

```
Legended[Show[{ParametricPlot[
    Hypocycloid[{5, 1}, θ], {θ, 0, Pi/3}, 
    PlotStyle -> Red], 
   ParametricPlot[
    Hypocycloid[{5, 1}, θ], {θ, Pi/3, 2 Pi/3 - 0.001}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Blue}], 
   ParametricPlot[
    Hypocycloid[{5, 1}, θ], {θ, 2 Pi/3, 3 Pi/3 - 0.001},
     PlotStyle -> {Green}], 
   ParametricPlot[
    Hypocycloid[{5, 1}, θ], {θ, 3 Pi/3, 4 Pi/3 - 0.001},
     PlotStyle -> {Orange}], 
   ParametricPlot[
    Hypocycloid[{5, 1}, θ], {θ, 4 Pi/3, 5 Pi/3 - 0.001},
     PlotStyle -> {Pink}], 
   ParametricPlot[
    Hypocycloid[{5, 1}, θ], {θ, 5 Pi/3, 6 Pi/3 - 0.001},
     PlotStyle -> {Magenta}]}, Axes -> None, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
 SwatchLegend[{Red, Blue, Green, Orange, Pink, 
   Magenta}, {"0≤θ<π/3", 
   "π/3≤θ<2π/3", 
   "2π/3≤θ<π", 
   "π≤θ<4π/3", 
   "4π/3≤θ<5π/3", 
   "5π/3≤θ<2π"}]]
```

[image]

Is it possible to take the same output with something quicker?
Something like different `PlotStyle`(s) according to the given `PlotRange`(s).

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1128)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do as in the link J.M. provided, define the plotted function as a piecewise function.  But you can make a custom piecewise color function,

```
regions = {"0≤θ<π/3", 
   "π/3≤θ<2π/3", 
   "2π/3≤θ<π", 
   "π≤θ<4π/3", 
   "4π/3≤θ<5π/3", 
   "5π/3≤θ<2π"};
colors = {Red, Blue, Green, Orange, Pink, Magenta};

colorfunc[θ_] = 
  Piecewise[Transpose[{colors, ToExpression /@ regions}]];
```

and then use that on your plot.  Here I'm feeding `colorfunction` the value `#3` which is the value of `theta` (I think `#1` and `#2` would be `x` and `y`).  Far as I can tell, the

```
ParametricPlot[Hypocycloid[{5, 1}, θ], {θ, 0, 2 Pi},
 ColorFunction -> (colorfunc[#3] &),
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 Axes -> None, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All,
 PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[colors, regions]]
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I guess you can use `Blend[]` then: `cf = With[{ba = Transpose[MapAt[ArrayPad[#, -1] &, Riffle[#, #] & /@ {Subdivide[Length[colors]], colors}, 1]]}, Blend[ba, #] &]; ParametricPlot[Hypocycloid[{5, 1}, t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, ColorFunction -> (cf[#3] &), PlotPoints -> 95]`

Comment: I had to stare at that for a long time to see what is going on lol.  I take it the benefit would be that you would not have to set the boundaries yourself, the plot would automatically be broken up into the number of colors you provide.

Comment: Yes, something like that. `Blend[]` effectively replaces `Piecewise[]` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Mesh` and `MeshShading` (with `colors` and `regions` from @JasonB's answer):

```
ParametricPlot[Hypocycloid[{5, 1}, θ], {θ, 0, 2 π}, 
    Mesh -> {Range[0, 2 π, π/3]}, MeshShading -> RotateRight[colors], MeshStyle -> None, 
    Axes -> None, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
    PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[colors, regions]]
```

[image]