# Different colours for different sectors of piecewise function

Tags: plotting, color, piecewise

I have some lines of code that generate numerical solutions to equations. Then I want to combine two of these in a piecewise function. The way I did it is the following -lf1[r] and lf4[r] are the aforementioned numerical solutions

```
test[r_] := 
 Piecewise[{{lf1[r], 0.688199 <= r <= 10}, {lf4[r], 
    0.687159 <= r <= 0.688199}}]
Show[Plot[test[r], {r, 0.676319, rmax}, PlotStyle -> {Thick}, 
  BaseStyle -> {18, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"\[Rho]", "L(\[Rho])"}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, rmax}, {0, 1.4}}], 
 Plot[x, {x, 0, 1.4}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}]]
```

The plot is the following

[image]

Then I would like to have different colours in the different sectors of the piecewise function. I found some excellent answers here and I tried to adopt them - particularly [in this link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1128/plotting-piecewise-function-with-distinct-colors-in-each-section?noredirect=1&lq=1). However, I am facing some difficulties that I do not understand.

Example 1: Different colours, wrong plot.

```
pwSplit[_[pairs : {{_, _} ..}]] := 
 Piecewise[{#}, Indeterminate] & /@ pairs

pwSplit[_[pairs : {{_, _} ..}, expr_]] := 
 Append[pwSplit@{pairs}, pwSplit@{{{expr, Nor @@ pairs[[All, 2]]}}}]
pw = Piecewise[{{lf4[r], 0.687159 <= r <= 0.688199}, {lf1[r], 
     0.688199 <= r <= 10}}];

Plot[Evaluate[pwSplit@pw], {r, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
 Axes -> True]
```

The plot is 
[image]

Example 2: This time I don't get many colours and I also get a wrong plot -if you see there is a black flat line in the bottom that should not be there

```
f = Piecewise[{{lf1[#], 0.688199 <= # <= 10}, {lf4[#], 
      0.687159 <= # <= 0.688199}}] &;
colorFunction = f;
piecewiseParts = Length@colorFunction[[1, 1]];
colors = ColorData[1][#] & /@ Range@piecewiseParts;
colorFunction[[1, 1, All, 1]] = colors;
Show[Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}, ColorFunction -> colorFunction, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotRange -> {{0, rmax}, {0, 1.4}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thick}], 
 Plot[x, {x, 0, 1.4}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}]]
```

[image]

I don't understand what I am doing wrong in either case and it is not clear if I should modify something due to the fact that I have numerical functions and not analytic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a single plot if you separate the [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise) conditions into separate [`ConditionalExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression) objects.

To do this, you can use an internal function to determine the intervals of validity for each piecewise condition, and then create a list of [`ConditionalExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression) objects. The internal, undocumented (and hence subject to change) function to use is `` PiecewiseDump`PWIntCases ``:

```
test[r_] := Piecewise[
    {
    {Exp[r], r<-1},
    {1-r^2, -2<r<1}, (* notice change in left endpoint! *)
    {Sin[Pi r], r>1}
    }
];
PiecewiseDump`PWIntCases[test[r],{{r,-3,3}},{}]
```

> {{-3 < r < -1, -1 <= r < 1, 1 < r < 3, r >= 3 || r <= -3}, {E^r, 1 - r^2, 
>     Sin[π r], 0}}

Even though I changed the conditions so that they overlap, `` PiecewiseDump`PWIntCases `` is smart enough to accommodate this change (the first condition took precedence over the second). We can use the above to create a list of [`ConditionalExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression) objects:

```
conditionals = MapThread[
    ConditionalExpression[#2, #1]&,
    PiecewiseDump`PWIntCases[test[r], {{r,-3,3}}, {}]
]
```

> {ConditionalExpression[E^r, -3 < r < -1], 
>    ConditionalExpression[1 - r^2, -1 <= r < 1], 
>    ConditionalExpression[Sin[π r], 1 < r < 3], 
>    ConditionalExpression[0, r >= 3 || r <= -3]}

Each [`ConditionalExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression) object is only valid over the given condition.

Visualization:

```
Plot[conditionals, {r, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

test[r_] := 
  Piecewise[{{Exp[r], r < -1}, {1 - r^2, -1 < r < 1}, {Sin[Pi r], 
     r > 1}}];

plotRng = {-3, 3};
```

Extract plot intervals from [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) and the specified `pltRng`

```
intervals = {Cases[test[r][[1, All, -1]], _?NumericQ, 2], plotRng} // 
     Flatten // Union // Partition[#, 2, 1] &;
```

[`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) each interval separately and combine with [`Show`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html)

```
Module[{n = 4},
 Show[Plot[test[r], {r, Sequence @@ #}, 
     PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][n++]] & /@ intervals, 
  PlotRange -> {plotRng, Automatic}]]
```

[image]