# Colour plot based on x-axis value

Tags: plotting, piecewise

I am trying to adapt [[this solution for colouring the different sections of a Piecewise function]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1132/34694)

I want to colour based on the x-axis value.  I have two functions I want to do this for, one is Piecewise the other can be written as Piecewise.

MWE

```
a[x_]:= x^2;
b[x_] = Log[x];
f = Piecewise[{{a[x], 0<= x<= 3}, {b[x], 3<x <= 7}}]

g = Piecewise[{{#^2, # <= 0}, {Log[#], 2 < #}}] &

colorFunction = f
piecewiseParts = Length@colorFunction[[1, 1]]
colors =  {Red, Green}
colorFunction[[1, 1, All, 1]] = colors

Plot[f, {x, -2, 4}, ColorFunction -> colorFunction, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

The linked example uses a Piecewise function defined like g (use g everywhere instead of g) - I need to use something that is formed like f.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat `f` like a pure function, but keep the definitions and dependencies of `a` and `b`:

```
a[x_] := x^2;
b[x_] := Log[x];
f = Piecewise[{{a[x], 0 <= # <= 3}, {b[x], 3 < # <= 7}}, 0] &;
colorFunction = f;
colors = {Red, Green};
colorFunction[[1, 1, All, 1]] = colors;
Plot[f[x], {x, -2, 4}, ColorFunction -> colorFunction, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

Returns:

[image]